# Python flask upload file but do not save and use

Tags: python, flask

My code currently takes in a file, and saves it to a preset directory, but is it possible to just use the file (read the file) and not save it?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return "yatta"
        else:
            return "file not allowed"

    return render_template("index.html")
```

I have tried both

file.read() and file.stream.read() but the return value of that is empty. I verify that the file exists in the uploaded directory and see that the file is not empty.

Comment: Aren't there any `file.read()`?

Comment: Tried that too :( @ForceBru

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read file data without saving it in Flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015550/read-file-data-without-saving-it-in-flask)

Comment: @ForceBru I tried using file.read() but the return value of that is empty, when I verify the saved file, I can see that the file's not empty.

Comment: have you tried using python's [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html)?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat, you've seen I marked ur question as duplicate. See the link, please. Maybe it'll help you.

Comment: @corvid I have not, I suspect that it won't work since file.stream itself is empty

Comment: I've replied to the same kind of question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42405115/7578261

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know that this is very outdated but for the sake of people landing here for similar inquiry, here it is if you want to save **AND** read your file after wards. Seems like Werkzeug's FileStorage class (which is the class to handle uploaded file in Flask) *pointing* to end of file after every action (saving or reading). So we have to move the pointer up to the beginning of the file before doing any subsequent action. I am using python's pandas in my answer below because I usually read csv into dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            file = request.files['file']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

                ## snippet to read code below
                file.stream.seek(0) # seek to the beginning of file
                myfile = file.file # will point to tempfile itself
                dataframe = pd.read_csv(myfile)
                ## end snippet

                return "yatta"
            else:
                return "file not allowed"

        return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: invaluable - file.stream.seek(0) is a hidden gem - huge thanks!

Comment: `file.stream.seek(0)` before `file.save(secure_filename(file.filename))` fixed my problem with empty file saving.
Thanxs alot!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're not saving the file with `file.save()` before you call `file.read()`.

So, your function would be:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            contents = file.read()
            # do something with file contents
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return "yatta"
        else:
            return "file not allowed"

    return render_template("index.html")
```

Hope this helps!