# Flask read uploaded json file

Tags: json, flask

I'm uploading a json file via flask, but I'm having trouble actually reading what is in the file.

```
# named fJson b/c of other json imports
from flask import json as fJson
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['file']
    # data = fJson.load(file)
    # myfile = file.read()
```

I'm trying to deal with this by using the 'file' variable. I looked at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.load, but I get the error "No JSON object could be decoded". I also looked at [Read file data without saving it in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015550/read-file-data-without-saving-it-in-flask) which recommended using file.read(), but that didn't work, returns either "None" or "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the position in the file was at the end. Doing

```
file.seek(0)
```

before doing a read or load fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> **Request.files**
>
> A MultiDict with files uploaded as part of a POST or PUT request. Each file is stored as FileStorage object. It basically behaves like a standard file object you know from Python, with the difference that it also has a save() function that can store the file on the filesystem.
>   http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.files

You don't need use json, just use read(), like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['file']        
    myfile = file.read()
```

Comment: When I try to print that, it only prints an empty string (and I checked, my file does have stuff in it)

Comment: Nice, share with us your solution.

Comment: I did below this one, but it won't let me accept it as an answer for another day.