# Pandas read_csv from FileStorage in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask

I'm trying to create pandas dataframe from uploaded csv file without saving file. When I do `df = pd.read_csv(request.file['file'])` pandas read this as a file but `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file` is shown. But this file is loaded properly to dataframe from console. `request.file['file'].stream` doesn't work also.

Comment: I had the same problem but, it was solved by using FileStorage.stream. It points to a temporary copy of the file. See the documentation here: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving your `csv` as a string try it using [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```
from io import StringIO
pd.read_csv(StringIO(request.file['file']))
```

Comment: No, I'm receiving `FileStorage` object since I'm using Flask

Comment: Call `read` method on `FileStorage` object. See - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20017830/2732017

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue here but maybe this could help you in your research.
so when you upload a file and handle it with flask you get a Werkzeug ~werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage object, when you do that without putting this  attribute : `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the html form if it's not specified the file will be empty.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Maybe you already know this, I hope it helps anyone else that finds this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).