# Direct to Google Bucket in flask

Tags: python-3.x

I share my solution to upload a file to a gcp bucket without saving the file locally.

```py
from google.cloud import storage

@app.route('/upload/', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # FileStorage object wrapper
        file = request.files["file"]                    
        if file:
            os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = app.config['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']
            bucket_name = "bucket_name" 
            storage_client = storage.Client()
            bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
            # Upload file to Google Bucket
            blob = bucket.blob(file.filename) 
            blob.upload_from_string(file.read())
```

Comment: not a question. write a blog or something.