# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage keeps popping up

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

```
def convertToBinaryData(filename):
    # Convert digital data to binary format
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        binaryData = file.read()
    return binaryData
```

This is my function for converting an image to binary...

```
uploaded_file = request.files['file']
if uploaded_file.filename != '':
    uploaded_file.save(uploaded_file.filename)
    empPicture = convertToBinaryData(uploaded_file)
```

and this is the block of code where the uploaded file is received and saved, however, when it runs, I get this error...

```
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage
```

I'm pretty new to python and I've been stuck on this for a while, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while calling '**convertToBinaryData**' you are passing '**uploaded_file**' which is not a filename but and object.

You need to pass the filename (with correct path if saved in custom location) to your '**convertToBinaryData**' funciton.

Something like this:

```
convertToBinaryData(uploaded_file.filename)
```

Comment: That's the filename on the client computer, it's not the name of the temporary file where the upload is saved.

Answer (score 4):

`uploaded_file` is not a filename, it's a Flask `FileStorage` object. You can read from this directly, you don't need to call `open()`.

So just do:

```
empPicture = uploaded_file.read()
```

See [Read file data without saving it in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015550/read-file-data-without-saving-it-in-flask)