# TypeError reading pdf from form using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

i need some help.
I want to watermark a pdf file that i pass from a form.
Then I encountered "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage" error.

This is my upload_file.html

```
<form action="/upload_file" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this is my test.py flask

```py
@app.route('/upload_file', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():

    pdf_file = request.files['file']
    watermark = "watermark.pdf"
    merged_file = "merged.pdf"

    input_file = open(pdf_file,'rb')
    input_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(input_file)

    watermark_file = open(watermark,'rb')
    watermark_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(watermark_file)

    pdf_page = input_pdf.getPage(0)

    watermark_page = watermark_pdf.getPage(0)

    pdf_page.mergePage(watermark_page)

    output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    output.addPage(pdf_page)

    merged_file = open(merged_file,'wb')
    output.write(merged_file)

    merged_file.close()
    watermark_file.close()
    input_file.close()

    return "Success"
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
  response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
  return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint]) 
(**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\abc\test.py", line 51, in upload_file
  input_file = open(pdf_file,'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: ive added traceback from cmd.

Comment: I suspect the file is already some sort of open handle when you receive it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage keeps popping up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63306549/4541045)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.files["name"]` can be directly used as a file-like, so you don't need to `open()` it

Additionally, you probably want to either only have ephemeral files writing to an `io.BytesIO()` or to name each file with something like a `uuid.uuid4()` so multiple clients won't conflict.

Comment: im sorry. in my line of coding, which part should i change and what can i add to it?