# How to process files from request in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask. I am trying to write a flask web service to parse files(txt files) and get results. Using postman send files to flask.

How can I read a file  and encoding it (like io.open(file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-16')) from the request and retrieve the content to parse it?

Here is my code:

```
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        files = request.files.getlist("file")
        for file in files:
            print(file.data)
            #.....do some processing
            
    return ""
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '127.0.0.1', port= 5000)
```

Comment: Did you try `file.read()`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20017830/434255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files = request.files.getlist("file")
for file in files:
    content = file.read() # Get the file contents
    file_name = file.filename # Get the file name
```