# Convert received json to dictionary, and save to local disk

Tags: python, json, flask

My flask server receives a json file.

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def trigger_processing():
   sent_files = request.files
   json_file = sent_files['file']
   print(json_file)
   data = json.load(json_file)
   print(data)
   return make_response(json.dumps({'fileid': "ok"}), 200)
```

Printing the `json_file` gives me:

```
<FileStorage: 'test.json' ('application/octet-stream')>
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2021 23:29:55] "POST /process HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

However the program fails when i try to convert json to dictionary.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 11 column 5 (char 213)
```

I want to be able to covert the json to dictionary.
Ideally, i would also like to save the received json file on the server's filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because `sent_files['file']` is a **FileStorage** object type, you need to read it and decode the bytes readed into a string. Then you can load it as a json.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import make_response
from tempfile import gettempdir
import json
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def trigger_processing():
    sent_files = request.files
    #read the file
    json_file_content = sent_files['file'].read().decode('utf-8')
    #load the string readed into json object
    json_content = json.loads(json_file_content)
    print(json_content)
    #generate the path where you want to save your file (in my case the temp folder)
    save_path = os.path.join(gettempdir(), sent_files['file'].filename)
    #and save the file
    with open(save_path, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(json_content, outfile, indent=2)
    return make_response(json.dumps({'fileid': "ok"}), 200)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but i got `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 11 column 5 (char 213)`. It gets triggered on this line `json_content = json.loads(json_file_content)`

Comment: Maybe the json in your file is incorrect, try some online json validator or post it here in the comment

Comment: I tried to put it in the comments, but it was 850 bytes, so if you are interested, the json is located here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/346e2599b8d8b622066ec988062d133b20210601084936/6d994a042ed8a12e03057b45bcf704c720210601084953/35b8be

Comment: the problem is that a comma is missing before the "annotations" variable

Comment: pay attention to the second variable "anchor", it will overwrite the first one. If you need to have more than one "anchor" object use an array. I suggest you to use some online json validator. ex: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Thank you very much! You were right, the json was invalid. I got a valid json but the code was failing. I managed to make it work by replacing your `save_path` line with this: `save_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sent_files['file'].filename)`. `gettempdir()` was not working for some reason (`NameError: name 'gettempdir' is not defined`). However, the json file that it now stores in the dir of the server is empty.

Comment: Have you imported it with: `from tempfile import gettempdir`?

Comment: With the import statement, your code worked, but still the json file is empty.

Comment: There is probably something else wrong, if the file is saved correctly with: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sent_files ['file'].filename)` then it must also work with `os.path.join(gettempdir(), sent_files['file'].filename)`

Comment: In both cased, the saved file is empty

Comment: Sorry my fault, I have updated the solution, now everything should work fine.