# What is the difference between werkzeug.filestorage.stream and werkzeug.filestorage.read()?

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library, werkzeug

I have a question about `flask werkzeug.filestorage`

I wrote the code using `flask` but I got a question

I use the code to get the image file data

`request.files['file']` is the `werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorageobject`

`request.files['file'].stream` works well.

[Read file data without saving it in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015550/read-file-data-without-saving-it-in-flask)
this question says, use like `request.files['file'].read()` but it occur error

I want to know why it occur errors and the difference between above code and the example of the use.

This is my total code

```py
from PIL import Image
app.route('/get_image', methods = ['POST'])
def image_check():
    # i works well
    img = Image.open(request.files['file'].stream)

    # it occur error
    # img = Image.open(request.files['file'].read())

    logger.info("file {}".format(type(request.files['file'])))
```

Comment: `Image.open()` expects either a filename (which will be opened for you), or an opened file or similar object (which will have `.read()` called on it).  It is not prepared to receive the contents of the file directly.

Comment: question from your link doesn't use `Image.open()` and this make big difference. `request.files['file'].read()` will work with functions which expect data - like standard `write(data)`