Upload file to s3 directly with flask
Im trying to upload a file to my s3 bucket using boto3
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "**"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "**"
BUCKET_NAME = 'dmfiles'
AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'

s3_client = boto3.client(
    service_name = 's3',
    region_name = AWS_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

#UPLOAD FILES TO AWS S3
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return "No file part", 400
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return "No selected file", 400
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

        # Upload file to S3

        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file,BUCKET_NAME,filename)
        print(f'upload_log_to_aws response: {response}')


I have seen similar questions but none solved my problem.
This is what i have tried so far. However it doesnt upload any file. What im doing wrong?

iirc, file is supposed to be a file object.    Perhaps this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015550/read-file-data-without-saving-it-in-flask

The 1st parameter to upload_file is the path to the file that is to be uploaded. I'm guessing that you should use filename for this parameter. The 3rd parameter is the key of the S3 object. I doubt that is the same as filename because filename relates to some local storage location (e.g. /tmp/dog.png) when you actually want a key that is, for example, dog.png.
