# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, curl

I am getting error `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` when trying to decode JSON.

The URL I use for the API call works fine in the browser, but gives this error when done through a curl request. The following is the code I use for the curl request.

The error happens at `return simplejson.loads(response_json)`

```
response_json = self.web_fetch(url)
response_json = response_json.decode('utf-8')
return json.loads(response_json)


def web_fetch(self, url):
    buffer = StringIO()
    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    curl.setopt(curl.URL, url)
    curl.setopt(curl.TIMEOUT, self.timeout)
    curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
    curl.perform()
    curl.close()
    response = buffer.getvalue().strip()
    return response
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/nab/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/nab/Desktop/pricestore/pricemodels/views.py" in view_category
  620.     apicall=api.API().search_parts(category_id= str(categoryofpart.api_id), manufacturer = manufacturer, filter = filters, start=(catpage-1)*20, limit=20, sort_by='[["mpn","asc"]]')
File "/Users/nab/Desktop/pricestore/pricemodels/api.py" in search_parts
  176.         return simplejson.loads(response_json)
File "/Users/nab/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py" in loads
  455.         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/Users/nab/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py" in decode
  374.         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
File "/Users/nab/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py" in raw_decode
  393.         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /pricemodels/2/dir/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Why decode the response? (`simple`)`json` can handle UTF-8 encoded JSON just fine.

Comment: Last but not least, what does `print repr(response_json)` tell you is being passed to `.loads()`?

Comment: One more: why use `simplejson` when you can just use the stdlib `json` (which is *the same library as `simplejson`*)?

Comment: When I do `print repr(response_json)` it just says `u''`

Comment: That is an empty string. Your `web_fetch()`  call failed.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting because it works in a browser.

Comment: You'll need to use `getinfo()` calls to figure out what the HTTP response code is, see what the server really sent you. Just because things work in a browser does not mean that using a script will be treated the same by the server. Cookies could be missing, the server could be responding differently based on other headers too.

Comment: As for your other questions.... I wish I could give better answers but I am not so sure on these decisions. Do you recommend switching to json over simplejson?  And requests over pycurl?

Comment: Note that `requests` offers native JSON support: `requests.get(url).json()`.

Comment: Ok thanks @MartijnPieters. This puts me on a good path to try to decipher the problem. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Ok update: You're right `requests` is soooo much easier. Thanks! Now I am seeing the response in `print repr(resonse_json)` which is good! Now I have an error at the line `return json.loads(response_json)` which is `TypeError` `Exception Value: expected string or buffer`

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Your code produced an empty response body; you'd want to check for that or catch the exception raised. It is possible the server responded with a 204 No Content response, or a non-200-range status code was returned (404 Not Found, etc.). Check for this.

Note:

- There is no need to use `simplejson` library, the same library is included with Python as the `json` module. (This note referred to the  question as it was originally formulated).
- There is no need to decode a response from UTF8 to Unicode, the `simplejson` / `json` `.loads()` method can handle UTF8-encoded data natively.
- `pycurl` has a very archaic API. Unless you have a specific requirement for using it, there are better choices.

Either [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io) or [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) offer much friendlier APIs, including JSON support.

#### Example using the Requests package

If you can, replace your call with:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()  # raises exception when not a 2xx response
if response.status_code != 204:
    return response.json()
```

Of course, this won't protect you from a URL that doesn't comply with HTTP standards; when using arbitrary URLs where this is a possibility, check if the server intended to give you JSON by checking the Content-Type header, and for good measure catch the exception:

```
if (
    response.status_code != 204 and
    response.headers["content-type"].strip().startswith("application/json")
):
    try:
        return response.json()
    except ValueError:
        # decide how to handle a server that's misbehaving to this extent
```

Comment: This is useful for determining when the `json` exists or to use `response.text` which is the alternative response.

Answer (score 234):

Be sure to remember to invoke `json.loads()` on the *contents* of the file, as opposed to the *file path* of that JSON:

```
json_file_path = "/path/to/example.json"

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as j:
     contents = json.loads(j.read())
```

I think a lot of people are guilty of doing this every once in a while (myself included):

```
contents = json.load(json_file_path)
```

Comment: I think in that case one should use `json.load()` instead.

Comment: The problem with `json.load()` is, if the file is empty then you will get the same error as the question. If you load the json content from HTTP response, you can check it via HTTP status code, but if you load it from file, then you will need to check if the file is empty or not. So it is better to use `j.read()` then check if it's empty.

Comment: I added an extra check on the file.is_empty() before loading. `p = Path("example.json"); if p.exists() and p.stat().st_size > 0 ...`

Answer (score 111):

Check the response data-body, whether actual data is present and a data-dump appears to be well-formatted.

In most cases your `json.loads`- `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error is due to :

- non-JSON conforming quoting
- XML/HTML output (that is, a string starting with <), or
- incompatible character encoding

Ultimately the error tells you that at the very first position the string already doesn't conform to JSON.

As such, if parsing fails despite having a data-body that looks *JSON like* at first glance, try replacing the quotes of the data-body:

```
import sys, json
struct = {}
try:
  try: #try parsing to dict
    dataform = str(response_json).strip("'<>() ").replace('\'', '\"')
    struct = json.loads(dataform)
  except:
    print repr(resonse_json)
    print sys.exc_info()
```

Note: Quotes within the data must be properly escaped

Comment: In the comments it was clear the OP got an empty response. Since `requests.get(url).json()` Just Works, the JSON isn't malformed either.

Comment: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` specifically occurs when an empty string is passed to json decode

Comment: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` also happens when the first line in the json response is invalid. Example response from running an `az cli` command is `["WARNING: The default kind for created storage account will change to 'StorageV2' from 'Storage' in the future",
 '{',`. This gave me the error that lead me here. The rest of the response IS a valid json object. Just that first line breaks things.

Comment: In some cases it is necessary to pass the header as `headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }`  along with the request URL in order to receive the valid JSON response.

Comment: .strip("'<>() ") Helped me, but .replace('\'', '\"') affects the content,
a better solution i found is using ast
import ast; 

ast.literal_eval( json_str.strip("'<>() ") )
Thanks & All the best!

Answer (score 54):

With the `requests` lib `JSONDecodeError` can happen when you have an http error code like 404 and try to parse the response as JSON !

You must first check for 200 (OK) or let it raise on error to avoid this case.
I wish it failed with a less cryptic error message.

**NOTE**: as Martijn Pieters stated in the comments servers **can** respond with JSON in case of errors (it depends on the implementation), so checking the `Content-Type` header is more reliable.

Comment: Sorry for the old comment, but could you link to an example?  I'm trying to take my skills from "perform action", to "attempt to perform action, return response, react accordingly".

Comment: @dcclassics: Example: it fails on server-side and server responds by showing an error page (HTML) instead of answering with JSON, so the code parsing the answer will attempt to read JSON but will fail on the HTML tags.

Comment: Servers can and do include JSON bodies in error responses. It’s not just 200 OK responses. You want to check the Content-Type header.

Answer (score 30):

Check encoding format of your file and use corresponding encoding format while reading file. It will solve your problem.

```
with open("AB.json", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as json_data:
     data = json.load(json_data, strict=False)
```

Comment: This worked for me with the small change of `encoding='utf-8'`, so I suppose sometimes you need to try a few things out.

Comment: Cannot agree more, it really depends on the setup...

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue trying to read json files with

```
json.loads("file.json")
```

I solved the problem with

```
with open("file.json", "r") as read_file:
   data = json.load(read_file)
```

maybe this can help in your case

Comment: I think it's important to make sure that the FILE PATH must be checked.

Answer (score 19):

A lot of times, this will be because the string you're trying to parse is blank:

```
>>> import json
>>> x = json.loads("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

You can remedy by checking whether `json_string` is empty beforehand:

```
import json

if json_string:
    x = json.loads(json_string)
else:
    # Your code/logic here 
    x = {}
```

Comment: While debugging further up in my code I was calling `response.read()` and then was dismayed when another call resulted in `Expecting value: line 1` etc.  Removed the debug statement and problem solved.

Comment: To debug, you can also use this nice website https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: it can also be an empty binary string starting with b. it's not te same if you use a if to detect it  :   b''

Comment: @PatriceG That is called a bytes literal and it works the same way in Python 3.7+ that I've tested

Comment: What is the correct way to handle this if output is of type b'bytes literal' ?  proc.communicate seems to be providing this and it can't be parsed as json (but it used to be fine pre py3 I think).

Answer (score 18):

I encounterred the same problem, while print out the json string opened from a json file, found the json string starts with 'ï»¿', which by doing some reserach is due to the file is by default  decoded with UTF-8, and by changing encoding to utf-8-sig, the mark out is stripped out and loads json no problem:

```
open('test.json', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Almost identical as your description, some weird character string at the start. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

This is the minimalist solution I found when you want to load json file in python

```py
import json
data = json.load(open('file_name.json'))
```

If this give error saying character doesn't match on position X and Y, then just add `encoding='utf-8'` inside the `open` round bracket

```py
data = json.load(open('file_name.json', encoding='utf-8'))
```

**Explanation**
`open` opens the file and reads the containts which later parse inside `json.load`.

*Do note that using `with open() as f` is more reliable than above syntax, since it make sure that file get closed after execution, the complete sytax would be*

```py
with open('file_name.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, in my case I solved like this:

```
import json

with open("migrate.json", "rb") as read_file:
   data = json.load(read_file)
```

Answer (score 6):

There may be embedded 0's, even after calling decode().  Use replace():

```
import json
struct = {}
try:
    response_json = response_json.decode('utf-8').replace('\0', '')
    struct = json.loads(response_json)
except:
    print('bad json: ', response_json)
return struct
```

Comment: response_json not defined

Comment: The original poster refers to the response json as response_json .

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly this issue using requests. 
Thanks to Christophe Roussy for his explanation.

To debug, I used:

```
response = requests.get(url)
logger.info(type(response))
```

I was getting a 404 response back from the API.

Comment: It can be simplified to `response.status_code` or `print(response.status_code)`.

Comment: Same. I was getting a 403 error. So my response looks like this,
`<Response [403]>`
 which isn't a valid json format

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem with requests (the python library). It happened to be the `accept-encoding` header.

It was set this way: `'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'`

I simply removed it from the request and stopped getting the error.

Answer (score 5):

Just check if the request has a status code 200. So for example:

```
if status != 200:
    print("An error has occured. [Status code", status, "]")
else:
    data = response.json() #Only convert to Json when status is OK.
    if not data["elements"]:
        print("Empty JSON")
    else:
        "You can extract data here"
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was doing file.read() two times in if and else block which was causing this error. so make sure to not do this mistake and hold contain in variable and use variable multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it occured because i read the data of the file using `file.read()` and then tried to parse it using `json.load(file)`.I fixed the problem by replacing `json.load(file)` with `json.loads(data)`

Not working code

```
with open("text.json") as file:
    data=file.read()
    json_dict=json.load(file)
```

working code

```
with open("text.json") as file:
   data=file.read()
   json_dict=json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Your `file` variable is the `fp` described in https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage, so use it like so: `json.load(file)`

Comment: @JesseH. isn't it what i have done in the not working code part? It throws the error

Comment: The reason it is not working is you are using `.read()` method on `file`. Read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906148/12678216 . You should remove that line, and see if it works.

Comment: @JesseH. Yes i have realized that `.read()` method is causing the issue so i have suggested a workaround in the answer. Why do you think this is a bad answer?

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was not using authentication in the request.

Answer (score 2):

I did:

1. Open `test.txt` file, write data
2. Open `test.txt` file, read data

So I didn't close file after 1.

I added

```
outfile.close()
```

and now it works

Comment: I also had a similar problem using two with statement, even though it should handle the closing by itself

Answer (score 1):

For me it was server responding with something other than 200 and the response was not json formatted. I ended up doing this before the json parse:

```
# this is the https request for data in json format
response_json = requests.get() 

# only proceed if I have a 200 response which is saved in status_code
if (response_json.status_code == 200):  
     response = response_json.json() #converting from json to dictionary using json library
```

Comment: This was the problem for me. The status code was 500 (internal server error) instead of 200, so no json was returned and therefore there was nothing in line 1 col 1 of the json. Always good to check that the request status code is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I received such an error in a Python-based web API's response `.text`, but it led me here, so this may help others with a similar issue (it's very difficult to filter response and request issues in a search when using `requests`..)

Using `json.dumps()` on the *request* `data` arg to create a correctly-escaped string of JSON before POSTing fixed the issue for me

```py
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it is because the server is giving http error occasionally. So basically once in a while my script gets the response like this rahter than the expected response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.<hr/>Powered by Tengine</body>
</html>
```

Clearly this is not in json format and trying to call `.json()` will yield `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

You can print the exact response that causes this error to better debug.
For example if you are using `requests` and then simply print the `.text` field (before you call `.json()`) would do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows user, Tweepy API can generate an empty line between data objects. Because of this situation, you can get "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" error. To avoid this error, you can delete empty lines.

For example:

```
 def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('sentiment.json', 'a', newline='\n') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True
```

Reference:
[Twitter stream API gives JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334038/twitter-stream-api-gives-jsondecodeerrorexpecting-value-s-err-value-from-n)

Comment: I don't think empty lines are a problem. It clearly states that the error is on line 1 column 1. I think this workaround works because it is removing the BOM from the file. You can quickly verify it:
1. Check the size of your original file (right click > Properties), it can be 134.859 bytes
2. Open the original file with Notepad++ 
3. Change the Encoding from "UTF-8-BOM" to "UTF-8". Save
4. Check the size again. It ca be 134.856 (3 bytes less)

Answer (score 0):

if you use headers and have `"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"` install brotli library with pip install. You don't need to import brotli to your py file.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurs, when making an [**HTTP `HEAD` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request to an API endpoint, which, for instance, would normally respond with JSON data in the response body to a `GET` request (similar to the FastAPI backend demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804)). However, a response to a `HEAD` method **does not** normally have a body.

Hence, when trying to call the `json()` method on the response, as follows:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

r = requests.head(url)  # perform a HEAD request
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())  # attempting to read an empty response body as JSON would raise an exception
```

would raise the following exception(s):

> `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
>
> ... During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> `requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] : 0`

Therefore, when performing `HEAD` requests, make sure that there is a body in the response (which normally there isn't), before calling `r.json()` method. You could use `print(r.content)` instead, which would print out the response content in byte form, or simply `b''`, if the response body was empty.

Answer (score 0):

For me the final solution was in the encoding setting.

My json was valid, but slightly different encoding (UTF-8 with BOM), created the same error.
So I specified the encoding as follows:

```
 with open(file, encoding="utf_8_sig") as j_file:
     json_file = json.load(j_file)
```

It might be that checking the exact encoding (using wordpad for example) and adjusting your encoding setting will help.

Answer (score -1):

#On Python 3.9, I used this:

````
with open("intents.json") as file:
    data=file.read()
    json_dict=json.dumps(data)```
````

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34892474)