# Submitting a JS array via AJAX to Django view returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

I have an array of objects that needs to be submitted to Django view.
I stringify it and checked result in console log. Up to this point it works. However, when I try to retrieve it in my view I get some errors.

I tried to edit my code similarly to what I've found on the topic, unfortunately nothing helped.
I tried `ast.literal_eval` instead of `json.loads`, passing `'items[]'` and collecting data via `request.POST.getlist` as well as solution with `request.body` and `request.is_ajax()`. Yet, neither allowed me to retrieve the data.

```
var items = [];
var formInput = $('#inputbox').val();
items.push({'item': formInput ,  'metrics': metrics.toString()});

$('#id_search').click(function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '{% url "list_of_items" %}',
            data: {'items': JSON.stringify(items),},

            success: function (response) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and in views.py:

```py
def list_of_items(request):
    data = request.POST.get('items')
    data_received = json.loads(data)

    #another approach:
    response_json = request.body
    struct = {}
    try:
        response_json = response_json.decode('utf-8').replace('\0', '')
        struct = json.loads(response_json)
    except:
        print('bad json: ', response_json)

    #(...)
```

I looks like an empty object is passed.

```
TypeError at /list_of_items
the JSON object must be str, not 'NoneType'
```

This view receives another POST request from the JS form within same template (list_of_items.html) and I wonder if it's interfering with my ajax POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the data correctly. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST):

> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters, providing that the request contains form data.

You need to send the data as `key:value` pair or you need to decode the request.body as

```
data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
data_received = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0), similar, to what you suggested and I get an empty object.

Comment: I've added changes to the code in the question field.

Comment: you don't have to follow both of the approaches. You are sending the data as `{'items': JSON.stringify(items),}, ` then you can get the data from `request.POST.get('items')`. Are you able to get the data from `request.POST.get('items')`?

Comment: No, I get ```None```.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue with your code and looke like `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` the culprit. Remove this line and then you should be able to get your data from `request.POST`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to send ajax request.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "list_of_items" %}',
        data: {'items': JSON.stringify(items),},

        success: function (response) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

I also think that you have bound the submit event and click event incorrectly. Also you are sending ajax request on submit event without preventDefault