# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm getting the following error message:

...File "c:\users\dockerhost\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I'm attempting to use requests to get the response headers.  I've done a lot of research on trying to resolve the jsondecodeerror.  However, I'm not finding a solution.

```
import requests
request.get('https://www.google.com/').json()

Error message.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Host\.virtualenvs\projects08-8iyGSYl4\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\host\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\users\host\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\users\host\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Try solution from this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0

Comment: @amrs-tech I attempted that solution with no success.   Did you attempt to resolve it?

Comment: No actually, that solution tells many approaches, have you tried of parsing your response and then call the json ?

Comment: You chained two calls, which of them causes the issues?

Comment: The documentation details this: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-headers Was that not the method  you were after?

Answer (score 7):

The JSON decoder expecting a value at the very first character of the very first line simply means that it is finding no content to parse. That is, the content of your response object is empty.

You should check the content of the server response with:

```
print(request.get(your_url).content)
```

to make sure that it is not empty and is actually valid JSON.

If it is indeed empty, it usually means that you are not sending to the server what it expects, and that you should fix the headers/cookies/authentication/API keys/parameters you send with the request.

Comment: It is not an empty file.

Comment: That specific error message you posted can only happen when the response content is empty.  If you are certain that the response is not empty and is actually valid JSON, you can parse it yourself with `import json` and `print(json.loads(request.get(your_url).text)))`.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation,

```
ResponseObj.json()
```

> Returns a JSON object of the result (if the result was written in JSON format, if not it raises an error)

You are getting an error because of the fact that the result isn't in JSON format.

If there is a valid JSON as the result,

```
>>> requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').json()
{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'delectus aut autem', 'completed': False}
```

The function does return a JSON.

Answer (score 2):

With the usage `request.get('https://www.google.com/').json()`
 you are blindly converting the HTTP response content to JSON. The response may or may not be a JSON depending on the URLS. Here , google page is HTML not JSON.

From the [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.7.0/user/quickstart/#json-response-content), its clear that, `json()` call will raise an error, if the content is not JSON.

However, you mentioned about response headers. Response headers can be accessed with `request.get('https://www.google.com/').headers` , which is a dictionary representation of headers. If you want that to be json, just load it like

```
import json
import requests
header_json = json.dumps(dict(requests.get('https://www.google.com/').headers))
pprint(header_json)
```

this would give you result like

```
{
    "Alt-Svc": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43,39\"",
    "Cache-Control": "private, max-age=0",
    "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",
    "Date": "Wed, 28 Aug 2019 06:20:28 GMT",
    "Expires": "-1",
    "P3P": "CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info.\"",
    "Server": "gws",
    "Set-Cookie": "######################removed purposefully##########################",
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "X-XSS-Protection": "0"
}
```

Is this something you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you update the link to the documentation please ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error, first check whether you're getting a `status_code`different from 200. Probably the server is returning a `<Response [204]>`

```
my_response = requests.get(MY_URL)
if my_response.status_code == 200:
    my_response.json()

else:
   ...
```