# ERROR: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python

I wanted to get some data via API from this url https://api.hooktheory.com/v1/users/auth

I can enter it with a key, but as soon as I want to request some data it won't work, because of the following error.

I already downloaded pip via https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and imported requests, I also tried it via conda install pip. Nothing works out and the problem still occurs. I already searched for some solutions in here, but its. not a duplicate. FYI: I work on a Mac OS X with visual studio.

```
import requests
import time

login = {"Accept": "application/json", 
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "username":"huks",
      "password": "XXXX"}


url = "https://api.hooktheory.com/v1/users/auth"
r = requests.post(url, data=login)
print(r.json())

time.sleep(5)

activkey = 'XXXX'
header = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + activkey}

r = requests.get(url+'trends/songs', headers=header)
r.json()

r = requests.get(url+'trends/nodes?cp=4', headers=header)
r.json()
```

Here is the traceback + error message:

```
File "/Users/marius/Desktop/INNOLAB/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 20, in <module>
    r.json()
  File "/Users/marius/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/marius/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/marius/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/marius/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Check out the `r.status_code` and `r.text`. It's probably because it's something wrong with your request and response is not a JSON.

Comment: Check your API link, I think you got a problem here: `.../authtrends/songs` when you add: `url+'trends/songs'`

Comment: Accept & Content-Type are headers not payload!?

Comment: @pako for r.text occurs TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.          


and  r.status_code is 200

Comment: @LêTưThành the API Link and the manual is mentioned there: https://www.hooktheory.com/api/trends/docs

Comment: @kris is correct but doesn't help anything

Comment: I don't see you re-assign `url='hooktheory.com/api/'`

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57686175/995052

Comment: @LêTưThành what do you mean by this? Sorry, am pretty new to programming. Where and why should I re-assign it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685622/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0-python)

Comment: Your current `url` is `"https://api.hooktheory.com/v1/users/auth"`. Then you append `trends/songs` by `url+'trends/songs'`=>`.../users/authtrends/songs`

Comment: @Kris thanks for the link, but I think it's different. The API supports xml and json, so I don't have to convert it

Comment: @hux0 did you do any debugging on what is the response you obtained rather than just saying its not working ?

Comment: i suspect it is an issue of conda. Not having this problem with requests from pip in a virtual env without conda... 
Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import time

login = {"Accept": "application/json", 
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "username":"huks",
      "password": "XXXX"}


url = "https://api.hooktheory.com/v1/users/auth"
r = requests.post(url, data=login)
print(r.json())

time.sleep(5)

activkey = 'XXXX'
header = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + activkey}

r = requests.get(url+'/trends/songs', headers=header)
r.json()

r = requests.get(url+'/trends/nodes?cp=4', headers=header)
print(r.text) #this will print what is the response you got!
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.json()) #this will work only if response is JSON
```

Hope the comments makes sense!

Comment: thanks! I did debugging and also tried your code just right now, but the same error is occurring.

Comment: what is the response text you receive?

Comment: same as before:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @hux dude you are not getting the point. response text is different. you are talking about the error. What does print(r.text) print?