# Parsing multiple json files into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have set of 10k json files that I am trying to parse into single dataframe.

I started first with parsing single file to make sure I am parsing it correctly for values i need:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

file = open("C:/Test/datapush_event_2019-09-25T16-02-30.4Z.json")
data = json.load(file)
data
```

This worked perfectly however when i try to extend this on all files that i have just in different directory using for loop I am getting weird error:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import glob
data = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob('C:/Data2/*.json'):
    with open(file) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        df = json_normalize(json_data, record_path='events', meta=[['metadata', 'serial_number']])
        data =data.append(df)


Error code:

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-44-9feedda31786> in <module>
      5 for file in glob.glob('C:/Data2/*.json'):
      6     with open(file) as json_file:
----> 7         json_data = json.load(json_file)
      8         df = json_normalize(json_data, record_path='events', meta=[['metadata', 'serial_number']])
      9         data =data.append(df)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 296         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    297 
    298 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am adding the sample of json file:

```
    { 
   "metadata":{ 
      "timezone":{ 
         "location":"Atlanta",
         "offset":120
      },
      "serial_number":"12345",
      "device_type":"Test"
   },
   "from":"2019-09-25T16:02:30.400Z",
   "events":[ 
      { 
         "timestamp":"2019-09-25T16:02:30.400Z",
         "type":"ZONE_EXIT",
         "tracked_object":{ 
            "id":53778,
            "type":"PERSON",
            "position":{ 
               "x":-3878,
               "y":-1606,
               "type":"FOOT",
               "coordinate_system":"REAL_WORLD_IN_MILLIMETER"
            },
            "person_data":{ 
               "height":1687
            }
         },
         "element":{ 
            "id":"4bea9786-a840-4895-b5ea-4216753854d7",
            "name":"Count Zone Left",
            "type":"ZONE_GEOMETRY"
         }
      },
      { 
         "timestamp":"2019-09-25T16:02:30.400Z",
         "type":"ZONE_EXIT",
         "tracked_object":{ 
            "id":53778,
            "type":"PERSON",
            "position":{ 
               "x":-3878,
               "y":-1606,
               "type":"FOOT",
               "coordinate_system":"REAL_WORLD_IN_MILLIMETER"
            },
            "person_data":{ 
               "height":1687
            }
         },
         "element":{ 
            "id":"e6311a10-5b0e-4aca-a97b-ad0e2f3827d3",
            "name":"ZoneOfInterest-Count01",
            "type":"ZONE_GEOMETRY"
         }
      },
      { 
         "timestamp":"2019-09-25T16:02:30.400Z",
         "type":"ZONE_EXIT",
         "tracked_object":{ 
            "id":53787,
            "type":"PERSON",
            "position":{ 
               "x":-7124,
               "y":-2329,
               "type":"FOOT",
               "coordinate_system":"REAL_WORLD_IN_MILLIMETER"
            },
            "person_data":{ 
               "height":1978
            }
         },
         "element":{ 
            "id":"e6311a10-5b0e-4aca-a97b-ad0e2f3827d3",
            "name":"ZoneOfInterest-Count01",
            "type":"ZONE_GEOMETRY"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Any suggested how to resolve this?
Or is there any better approach loading multiple json files into single dataframe in python?

Comment: can u manually check the file in which it exactly throws this exception ?

Comment: I agree with @venkatakrishnan - your code seems fine, it's likely to be a problem with the formatting of a specific file. Add some debugging to your code, and identify which file it fails on. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0 for suggestions.