# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0), its throwing error

Tags: python, json

Below Python code I am using that throws error, i tried readlines, json.loads as well but that doesnt seem to woork as well

```
with open('/Users/akshayarora/PythonCodes/Capstone1/Delhi.json') as data_file: 
    provinces_json = json.load(data_file)
```

```
var dataset = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "City": "Delhi",
        "State": "Delhi"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          77.266052,
          28.68161
        ]
      }
           ]
    }
           }
```

Comment: --> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)


I tries json.loads as well as but its also throwing error.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what the JSON looks like. It's most likely invalid.

Comment: It looks like: var dataset = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "City": "Delhi",
        "State": "Delhi"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          77.266052,
          28.68161
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "City": "Delhi",
        "State": "Delhi"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          77.266052,
          28.68161
        ]
      }
    }

Comment: like these i have many values, i have provided sample above

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON. Format the JSON as code, so that it's easier to read. Also, look for non-printing characters at the start of the file.

Comment: Please share the entire error message as well as a [mcve], in your post itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Comment: @AMC - i tries all those mentioned in the link above but same error is coming

Comment: @Akshay We still don't have the necessary information to reproduce this, so I'm not sure what you expect us to be able to do.

Comment: TRY WITH THIS JSON:

Comment: var dataset = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "City": "Delhi",
        "State": "Delhi"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          77.266052,
          28.68161
        ]
      }
           ]
    }
           }

Comment: Add that to your post, not as a comment, as others have already mentioned. Also, that looks like JavaScript.

Comment: That still isn't an [mcve]. **The code is incomplete, the data is both invalid JSON and invalid Python.** (it looks like JS)

Answer (score 1):

Thats not JSON... JSON is **not** javascript, it is a way of serializing javascript (or thats what it was designed for). Your `var dataset = {` is wrong, JSON is not a programming language its a way of storing data structures

Also your JSON is malformed. Your close bracket is in the wrong place

```
 {"features": [ ... /* HERE */ } /* NOT HERE (where you currently have it) }
```

(Note comments are not supported in the JSON standard, this is just for show)

Comment: I have provided the sample only, so its missing here. in actual file its present

Comment: Are you sure? Your saying when you copied it you missed a bracket within it another bracket?? Have you tried this to see if it works?

Comment: @Akshay _I have provided the sample only, so its missing here. in actual file its present_ Then it's not a [mcve], right?

Comment: *reproducable* if your code does not actually show the issue then its pointless. This answer is correct for the code you provided, please try it and/or fix your question

Comment: @AMC -I have provided sample json through this i am able to reproduce it

Comment: @Akshay As I already wrote in another comment, that isn't valid JSON, nor is it even valid Python. We're still missing the entire error message, and the code looks incomplete.

Comment: @Akshay What changed? I can't see any difference.