# Pull data from server using Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I did like to pull data from local server and push to online server using requests but I am getting this error *JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)*

Here is the code to server url and api_key, kindly not that this not the exact url and api key due to privacy issues
:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
from functools import reduce,partial
import re
import redcap
from redcap import Project

url_link = "https://localhost/odk/api/"
api_key = '1AF3249E1E09474E'
re = requests.get(url = url_link, data = {'key': api_key}) 
re.json()
```

I am not able to get that data, what am I missing. could I kindly get help

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0

Comment: Your error suggest that what is response is not legal JSON, please replace `re.json()` with `print(re.text)` and write what is its output

Comment: @Daweo says 'str' object is not callable