# How to read json to pandas dataframe from a zipped file?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a very large in size zipped file (1.5G), there are 500 sub folders inside the zipped file.And there are 5000 json file under each sub folder.

I would like to read the json to python dataframe and have the code & error like below.
Could you pls suggest me how to fix it? Thanks.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('20APIJSON.zip', 'r') as z:
   for filename in z.namelist():
      with z.open(filename) as f:
        data = f.read()
        json_file = json.loads(data)
```

### error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e235c823f732> in <module>()
      9       with z.open(filename) as f:
     10         data = f.read()
---> 11         json_file = json.loads(data)
     12         l.append([json_file['FullStudy']['Study']['ProtocolSection']['IdentificationModule']['NCTId'],
     13                   json_file['FullStudy']['Study']['ProtocolSection']['StatusModule']['OverallStatus'],

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `filename` in your for loop is the path to the subfolders inside the zipped file and not the JSON file itself.