# Fetch data from SQL Server and convert to JSON / Error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, sql-server

I would like fetch data from a SQL Server database and transform the result in a JSON format.

Thats not difficult, but one column is already a JSON and I would like separate it, but the result is a little bit confusing.

My code:

```
    rows = cursor.fetchall() 
    print (rows)
    objects_list = []
    for row in rows:
        d= collections.OrderedDict()
        #d["Bestelldatum"]= row[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        a = json.loads(row[0])
        #print(a)
        #d["Adresse"] = row[0]
        #d["Tor"] = a["tor"]
        #d["Stiege"] = a["stg"]
        #d["Stock"] = a["stk"] 
        #d["Tür"] = a["tür"]
        #d["PLZ"] = a["plz"]

        objects_list.append(d)
    j = json.dumps(objects_list, ensure_ascii=False)
    print (j)
```

My problem is row 1, that is a JSON, see the pic

[Picture from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg2bW.png)

If I run it so, I get this error messange

> in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> File "C:\Users\acas1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> File "C:\Users\acas1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I guess something is wrong with the JSON data which I get from the database
I don't understand why some data have backslashes, because at SQL they not exist.
Thats the result if I fetch just the raw data from the database:

[Picture from result in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiOb9.png)

I tried everything that they say in this post [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)
 but nothing helps.

I hope someone have an idea

Comment: can you post the data shown in the second picture instead of the image?

Comment: `Adresse` for rows 3, 5 and 12 are empty or null. Is it possible that `json.loads()` could be complaining about that?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you were right, json.loads() could not handle empty rows, thank you