# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value when loading tf.Keras model

Tags: json, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

When I try to load my trained `tf.keras` model, I get the error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value`.
The issue is not reproducible, i.e., I get the error when I try to load a model that I have trained on a cluster and downloaded to my computer. When I tried to just compile, save, and load the same model, the error doesn't appear.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

The following code **works** (as opposed to loading the trained model):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as ks
import numpy as np
import os
def UNet(n_classes, input_shape = (256, 256, 3), dropout = 0.05,
         ops = {"activation" : "relu",
                "padding" : "same",
                "kernel_initializer" : "he_normal"
        }):
    # input layer
    inputz = ks.layers.Input(shape = input_shape)
    
    # encoder part
    ## 1st convolution
    c1 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), **ops)(inputz)
    c1 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), **ops)(c1)
    ## 1st max pooling
    p1 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(c1)
    
    ## 2nd convolution
    c2 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), **ops)(p1)
    c2 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), **ops)(c2)
    ## 2nd max pooling
    p2 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(c2)
    
    ## 3rd convolution
    c3 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), **ops)(p2)
    c3 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), **ops)(c3)
    ## 3rd max pooling
    p3 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(c3)
    
    ## 4th convolution
    c4 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), **ops)(p3)
    c4 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), **ops)(c4)
    ## Drop
    d4 = ks.layers.Dropout(dropout)(c4)
    ## 4th max pooling
    p4 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(d4)
    
    ## 5th convolution
    c5 = ks.layers.Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), **ops)(p4)
    c5 = ks.layers.Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), **ops)(c5)
    ## Drop
    d5 = ks.layers.Dropout(dropout)(c5)
    
    # decoder part
    ## 1st up convolution
    us6 = ks.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2))(d5)
    up6 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, (2, 2), **ops)(us6)
    ## merge
    ct6 = ks.layers.concatenate([d4, up6], axis = 3)
    uc6 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), **ops)(ct6)
    uc6 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), **ops)(uc6)
    
    ## 2nd up convolution
    us7 = ks.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2))(uc6)
    up7 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, (2, 2), **ops)(us7)
    ## merge
    ct7 = ks.layers.concatenate([c3, up7], axis = 3)
    uc7 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), **ops)(ct7)
    uc7 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, (2, 2), **ops)(uc7)
     
    ## 3rd up convolution
    us8 = ks.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2))(uc7)
    up8 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (2, 2), **ops)(us8)
    ## merge
    ct8 = ks.layers.concatenate([c2, up8], axis = 3)
    uc8 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), **ops)(ct8)
    uc8 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), **ops)(uc8)
     
    ## 4th up convolution
    us9 = ks.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2))(uc8)
    up9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (2, 2), **ops)(us9)
    ## merge
    ct9 = ks.layers.concatenate([c1, up9], axis = 3)
    uc9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), **ops)(ct9)
    uc9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), **ops)(uc9)
    uc9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(2, (3, 3), **ops)(uc9)
    
    # output layer
    if n_classes > 2:
        activ = "softmax"
    else:
        activ = "sigmoid"
    outputz = ks.layers.Conv2D(n_classes, 1, activation = activ)(uc9)
    
    model = ks.Model(inputs = [inputz], outputs = [outputz])
    print(model.summary())
    print(f'Total number of layers: {len(model.layers)}')
    return model

# get model
model = UNet(n_classes = 5)

class UpdatedMeanIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
  def __init__(self,
               y_true = None,
               y_pred = None,
               num_classes = None,
               name = None,
               dtype = None):
    super(UpdatedMeanIoU, self).__init__(num_classes = num_classes,
                                         name = name, dtype = dtype)

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None):
    y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis = -1)
    return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
mIoU = UpdatedMeanIoU(num_classes = 5)



lr_sched = ks.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate = 1e-3,
    decay_steps = np.floor(50),
    decay_rate = 0.995)

optimizer = ks.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate = lr_sched, clipnorm = 1)

lozz = ks.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = lozz,
              metrics = [mIoU])

model.save("G:\\mot", save_format = "tf")
os.chdir("G:\\mot")
trained_model = ks.models.load_model("G:\\mot", custom_objects = {"UpdatedMeanIoU": mIoU})
```

The part code that does not work just includes a `model.fit` between `model.compile` and `model.save`.

The corrupt model can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o9c7umyw3b4862y/AAB-sdyOpOrXe_7Z1bZ5H0Tpa?dl=0).

This is the full error message:

```
trained_model = ks.models.load_model(moddir,\
                                     custom_objects = {"UpdatedMeanIoU": mIoU})
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-140-4d44f44a3739>", line 1, in <module>
    trained_model = ks.models.load_model(moddir,\

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 206, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 155, in load
    keras_loader.finalize_objects()

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 626, in finalize_objects
    self._reconstruct_all_models()

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 645, in _reconstruct_all_models
    self._reconstruct_model(model_id, model, layers)

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 661, in _reconstruct_model
    config = json_utils.decode(

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\json_utils.py", line 62, in decode
    return json.loads(json_string, object_hook=_decode_helper)

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

**Edit:**

I can load the model on the server where I trained it (in a separate Python session). However, I cannot do the same on my computer after downloading the files. Are there some hidden files the model depends on? Or can there be problems with different OS or different module versions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try recent TF/keras version (say 2.7)? I didn't notice this error with recent versions. Also, please share a toy data to run model.fit (without this saving and loading works as expected). [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jvishnuvardhan/277a9e26c269a33abbc2644db0a1f4aa/untitled1123.ipynb) is a gist for my reference. Thanks

Comment: A TensorFlow update solved the issue.