# JSONDecodeError when trying to extract a json

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, request

I am getting this error every time i try to extract the json in this api
Request_URL='https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/api/group=quotes&method=realtimeSentimentIndex&enabled=true&key=bsq3l3p5lc8w4s0c&type=swfx&jsonp=_callbacks____1kvynkpid'

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get(Request_URL)
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
```

Comment: JSON that you are working with is malformed

Comment: how do I fix that ?

Comment: Put `print()` calls in your program to discover what you are getting back from `requests.get()`. It's  clearly not what your code is assuming.

Comment: print `r.json()` and see what is the problem

Comment: the same error again, JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I am sure @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ (I will get the right user right one of these days) meant to say `print(r.text)` to see the string that is coming back to see why it does not parse as valid `JSON`. Of course, we already *know* that the call to `r.json()` throws an exception so there is no way that "printing" it is going to be helpful.

Comment: @Booboo yeah My bad, I meant `r.text`

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ  It's off-topic but: Why ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ and not ARMAN, which is more readily typed in English-speaking countries (this is an English-speaking website)? I had to  copy and paste your name. What character set is that from?

Comment: I don't remember why did I write it like this, I didn't know it causes a problem for mentioning @Booboo

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ When you want to send a message to somebody you can type `@` followed by the first couple of letters of their name and SO will show you all the matching names of people who have posted messages with that prefix and then just select from those matches. But if I type in @AR, nothing comes up and I did not even initially realize your name was not composed of ASCII characters. I have no idea how to enter ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ from my keyboard so I had to copy and paste this from your comment. Not a big deal but it took me a few seconds to realize what was going on.

Comment: I believe you posted `Request_URL` incorrectly since I got a 404 Not found error. I suspect that it is ``'https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/api?group=quotes&method=realtimeSentimentIndex&enabled=true&key=bsq3l3p5lc8w4s0c&type=swfx&jsonp=_callbacks____1kvynkpid'`,  that is with '...?group=...' instead of '.../group=...', but you will have to verify that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Comment: Yes it does, thanks @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: @Bayrem, the only thing I did is put "[python] JSONDecodeError" into the search field above to find that question. Do that before writing another question and waiting for answers, you'll have answers much faster.

Comment: much appreciated advice @UlrichEckhardt !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the response coming back is in `JSONP` format. That is, it is JavaScript consisting of a call to a function with an argument that is a JavaScript *structure* (which *should* be a valid `JSON` string if it had single quotes around it, but there is no guarantee that it is). In part it looks like:

```JavaScript
_callbacks____1kvynkpid([{"id":"10012" ...])
```

So we need to first remove the JavaScript call, which are the leading characters up to and including the first `(` character and the final `)`:

```py
import requests
import json

request_url = 'https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/api?group=quotes&method=realtimeSentimentIndex&enabled=true&key=bsq3l3p5lc8w4s0c&type=swfx&jsonp=_callbacks____1kvynkpid'

r = requests.get(request_url)
text = r.text
idx = text.index('(')
# skip everything up to and including opening '(' and then skip closing ')'
text = text[idx+1:-1]
print(json.loads(text))
```

Prints:

```
[{'id': '10012', 'title': 'ESP.IDX/EUR', 'date': '1636925400000', 'long': '71.43', 'short': '28.57'}, {'id': '10104', 'title': 'AUS.IDX/AUD', 'date': '1636925400000', 'long': '70.59', 'short': '29.41'}, {'id': '10266', 'title': 'NLD.IDX/EUR', 'date': '1636925400000', 'long': '73.48', 'short': '26.52'},

... data too big too fully reproduce

 {'id': '82862', 'title': 'MAT/USD', 'date': '1636925400000', 'long': '70.27', 'short': '29.73'}, {'id': '82866', 'title': 'ENJ/USD', 'date': '1636925400000', 'long': '72.16', 'short': '27.84'}]
```

In this case the structure when interpreted as a string adhered to the `JSON` format and so we were able to parse it with `json.loads()`. But what if the JavaScript structure had been (in part):

```JavaScript
[{'id':'10012'}]
```

This is both legal JavaScript and legal Python, but not legal `JSON` because strings must be enclosed within double-quotes for it to be valid `JSON`. But since it is legal Python, we could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval):

```python
import requests
import ast

request_url = 'https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/api?group=quotes&method=realtimeSentimentIndex&enabled=true&key=bsq3l3p5lc8w4s0c&type=swfx&jsonp=_callbacks____1kvynkpid'

r = requests.get(request_url)
text = r.text
idx = text.index('(')
# skip everything up to and including opening '(' and then skip closing ')'
text = text[idx+1:-1]
print(ast.literal_eval(text))
```

Of course, for the current situation both `json.loads` and `ast.literal_eval` happened to work. However, if the JavaScript structure had been:

```JavaScript
[{id:'10012'}]
```

This is valid JavaScript but, alas, not valid Python and cannot be parsed with either `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval`.