# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0), I am getting this error

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, urlopen

How to fix this error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)?
Below is the code

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    api_url = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=London&mode=html&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22"
url_result = urlopen(api_url)
data = url_result.read()
data=data.decode('utf-8')
import json
json_data = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: because your api_url is wrong

Comment: The message is telling you that `data` is not valid JSON. It's probably empty. Fix your code to check it, instead of assuming it is valid.

Comment: api probably returns empty data. Can't you print it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a request with `mode=html` then attempting to parse the response as JSON. You can dynamically pick up the correct urls by first getting a list of the available samples (and modes) from the base domain. The filter for what you want. JSON is the default to doesn't need the mode specified. The advantage here is you dynamically pick up the appid.

I show html and JSON responses below.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://samples.openweathermap.org/').json()
    samples = r['products']['current_weather']['samples'] 
    url_html = [sample for sample in samples if 'London&mode=html' in sample][0]
    print(url_html)
    print()
    r = s.get(url_html)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup.get_text())
    print()
    url_json = [sample for sample in samples if 'London&appid' in sample][0]
    print(url_json)
    print()
    r = s.get(url_json).json()
    print(r)
```