# Received JSONDecode Error from Zendesk API request

Tags: python, api, request, zendesk

I'm following this [tutorial](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/developer-tools/working-with-the-zendesk-apis/making-requests-to-the-zendesk-api/) ("Getting data from your Zendesk product") and I got a Response [200], which supposedly means that my request was successful. However when I did `data = response.json()`, I received the JSONDecoder error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I've tried debugging with the different solutions from other Stackoverflow [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0), but it hasn't worked. Please illuminate me!

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [mcve] so it's possible to assist you.

Comment: what'll be helpful? because i can't reveal my zendesk account details to access the API

Comment: The question suggests that response is probably `text` and not `json`. So try `response.text` initially.

Comment: You're trying to access `response.json()` before checking `response.status_code`. There is a good chance that your request was not successful.

Comment: Hello I already ran the response.status_code which resulted in Response[200], so i know it's successful

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the code in thq question, the first (or most likely) error is that the response type might not be `json`. So whilst you are getting a success (`200`) the return value is likely to be `text`.

In the past i have used something like this:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.whois.com/whois/'

r = requests.get(url)


if r.status_code==200:
    # page works, check if text or json response
    if r.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/html; charset=UTF-8':
        print(r.text)
    
    
else:
    print('no website')
```

The alternative response type for json is:

```
'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

So you could check for this directly.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response!

I included your code and it printed out a bunch of HTML gibberish :| i think ill contact zendesk developer community then. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You are welcome,  in the link that you posted one of the comments is that the `json` might not be properly formed. This might be the case for you. Also, you might wish to post the "gibberish" as it could be meaningful to resolving the problem....