# I need help creating a simple python script that stores an attribute value from a custom json file

Tags: python, python-3.x

**JSON file looks like this:**

```
{"Clear":"Pass","Email":"noname@email.com","ID":1234}
```

There are hundreds of json files with different email values, which is why I need a script to run against all files.

I need to extract out the value associated with the Email attribute, which is **nooname@email.com**.

I tried using import json but I'm getting a decoder error:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Script looks like this:

```
import json
json_data = json.loads("file.json")
print (json_data["Email"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Be sure to remember to invoke json.loads() on the contents of the file, as opposed to the file path of that JSON` https://stackoverflow.com/a/58647394/11280068

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), `json.loads()` takes a `str`, `bytes` or `bytearray` as argument. So if you want to load a json file this way, you should pass the content of the file instead of its path.

```py
import json
file = open("file.json", "r") # Opens file.json in read mode
file_data = file.read()
json_data = json.loads(file_data)
file.close() # Remember to close the file after using it
```

You can also use `json.load()` which takes a `FILE` as argument

```py
import json
file = open("file.json", "r")
json_data = json.load(file)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

your script needs to open the file to get a file handle, than we can read the json.
this sample contains code that can read the json file. to simulate this, it uses a string that is identical with the data coming from the file.

```
import json

#this is to read from the real json file
#file_name = 'email.json'
#with open(file_name, 'r') as f_obj:
   #json_data = json.load(f_obj)

# this is a string that equals the result from reading json file
json_data = '{"Clear":"Pass","Email":"noname@email.com","ID":1234}'
json_data = json.loads(json_data)
print (json_data["Email"])
```

result: `noname@email.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
with open("file.json", 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    #convert json to python dict
    tmp = json.loads(file_content)
    email = tmp["Email"]
```

As already pointed out in previous comments, json.loads() take contents of a file rather than a file.