# When passing a list to an api I get the following error code "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json, list, api, pokeapi

So I have been working on creating a mini pokedex using the poke api and I am stuck in a step.

This is what I have:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

pokemon_list = ["charizard", "gengar", "venusaur","golbat","gyarados","lapras", "dragonite", "infernape", "staraptor", "giratina"]
# Create empty lists to append all data:
name, height, weight = [],[],[]


# Get data from API
for pokemon in pokemon_list:
    res = requests.get(f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{pokemon}/")
    pokedata = json.loads(res.text)
    # Append data to the list:
    name.append(pokedata["name"])
    height.append(pokedata["height"])
    weight.append(pokedata["weight"])

ddata = {"Name": name, "Height": height, "Weight": weight} 
df_data = pd.DataFrame(ddata)
print(df_data)
```

and this is the TraceBack I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    pokedata = json.loads(res.text)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```

P.S.: if I try to read just one pokemon instead of a list, it works fine, but whenever I try to use a list with the for loop, I get this error. Any help you guys can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Comment: Please search for the error message online before asking yet another similar question. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What is the *exact* value of `res.text` that produces the error?  The rest of the code is irrelevant.  Also `res.json()` is a method to retrieve a JSON response.  No need to `json.loads()` yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `res.text` is `'Not Found'` in the failing case.  Don't try to read the JSON if the result fails.  FYI, debug yourself by `print(res.text)` before the line that fails.

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

pokemon_list = ["charizard", "gengar", "venusaur","golbat","gyarados","lapras", "dragonite", "infernape", "staraptor", "giratina"]
#Create empty lists to append all data:
name, height, weight = [],[],[]

#Get data from API
for pokemon in pokemon_list:
    res = requests.get(f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{pokemon}/")
    if res.ok:
        pokedata = res.json()
        # Append data to the list:
        name.append(pokedata["name"])
        height.append(pokedata["height"])
        weight.append(pokedata["weight"])
    else:
        print(f'{pokemon} not found')

ddata = {"Name": name, "Height": height, "Weight": weight} 
df_data = pd.DataFrame(ddata)
print(df_data)
```

Output:

```
giratina not found
        Name  Height  Weight
0  charizard      17     905
1     gengar      15     405
2   venusaur      20    1000
3     golbat      16     550
4   gyarados      65    2350
5     lapras      25    2200
6  dragonite      22    2100
7  infernape      12     550
8  staraptor      12     249
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason, Giratina cannot be found in the pokeapi, I just changed it to a different pokemon, and it works!