# Spotify API, getting 404 as a response trying to find current song

Tags: python, spotify

Am trying to make a program that finds the current song playing and then to put it an one of my playlists. But am getting a 404 response when a trying to obtain the current playing song.

This is how I am getting my access token:

```py
def get_token():
    auth_str = client_id + ":" + client_secret
    auth_bytes = auth_str.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_base64,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token
```

This is how I am creating the headers:

```py
def get_headers(token):
    return {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
```

This is how I am trying to get the current playing song uri:

```py
def get_current_track_and_post_in_playlist(token):
    headers = get_headers(token)
    result = get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing', headers=headers)
    playlist_id = "0p4d0akcszc87kcf0pym6qws1"
    print(result)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)["item"]["uri"]
    print(json_result)

    playlist_put = post(f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks?uris={json_result}', headers=headers)
```

When am printing the result in get_current_track_and_post_in_playlist function i get a <Response [404]>. Can someone help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasons is required a `user authentication` for those two REST APIs.

[Get Currently Playing Track](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track/)

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing
```

[Add Items to Playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-playlist-tracks/)

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks
```

It needs to get token by [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/)

So I will  demo by local server with [`Flask`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/)

This overall steps
[image]

#### # Step 1

I play a song by browser. it will add into my playlist

[image]

#### # Step 2

Running local redirect server with this code with `add-song.py` file name.

You needs to config the `Redirect URIs` of your application in your dashboard.

```
https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications
```

[image]

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/callback' # your redirect URI
CLIENT_ID = "<your client ID>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your client Secret>"
SCOPE = [
    "user-read-playback-state",
    "app-remote-control",
    "user-modify-playback-state",
    "playlist-read-private",
    "playlist-read-collaborative",
    "user-read-currently-playing",
    "user-read-playback-position",
    "user-library-modify",
    "playlist-modify-private",
    "playlist-modify-public",
    "user-read-recently-played",
    "user-read-private",
    "user-library-read"   
]

def get_headers(token):
    return {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    spotify = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, scope=SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
    authorization_url, state = spotify.authorization_url(AUTH_URL)
    return redirect(authorization_url)

# your redirect URI's path
@app.route("/callback", methods=['GET'])
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    res = requests.post(TOKEN_URL,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET),
        data={
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI
        })
    access_token = res.json()['access_token']
    listObj = []
    listObj.append(res.json())

    # get current playing
    headers = get_headers(access_token)
    result1 = requests.get(url='https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing', headers=headers)
    current_song = result1.json()
    listObj.append(current_song)

    # Add new song into playlist with current playing song
    playlist="<your playlist ID>"
    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{0}/tracks".format(playlist)
    # current_song['item']['uri']  = 'spotify:track:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    params = {'uris': current_song['item']['uri']}
    result2 = requests.post(url,
        params=params,
        headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token)})
    added_song = result2.json()    
    listObj.append(added_song)
    return listObj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000,debug=True) # your redirect URI's port
```

```
$ python add-song.py
```

#### #3 Login by Browser

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

login your Spotify credential
[image]

Before add Song
[image]

After added Song
[image]

In the browser,  will display current play song information and added song's `snapshot_id`.
[image]

The key is playing song's track URI needs to set a parameter of add playlist.

```
current_song['item']['uri']
```

#### #Step 4~6

It is running by inside code.

I hope to this demo your are looking for solution.

Comment: Really nice explanation, I apricate your time to go in that much detail. But when am running http://localhost:3000/login, to login, am get the following, INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI. I changed the client id and secret. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: I updated my answer, You needs to config the `Redirect URIs` of your application in your dashboard.

Comment: now it works, and i get into the cookies site, but when I accept the cookies I get this error, requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) . Sorry for the hustle but am not good at debugging json.

Comment: It is good progress, I don't the reason of cookies but someone has same problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)