# Token Works For Search Reference But Not For Player or Devices

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, spotify, bearer-token

I successfully obtain the token and make requests to search a song using titles. However, when I try to add a song using uri to user's queue, I get 401 permission missing error. I checked internet. My scopes are fine too:

```
let scopes = "user-read-private user-modify-playback-state user-read-playback-state user-read-currently-playing playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private playlist-read-private"
```

User logged out on all devices. I tried Postman, too. Still get the same result although token works for searching songs.

Comment: Two major different flows token in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization)
 [`Client credentials`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/client-credentials-flow) flow and [`Authorization code`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow) flow
If get token by  `Client credentials`, you can search song but can't add a song into playlist. This example can [add a song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419872/spotify-api-getting-404-as-a-response-trying-to-find-current-song/75424917#75424917).