# How to get redirect url from spotify authorized url

Tags: python-3.x

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
CLIENT_ID = SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID
REDIRECT_URI = SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI

AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
auth_params = {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'response_type': 'code',
    'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
}

auth_url = f"{AUTHORIZATION_URL}?{urlencode(auth_params)}"
print(auth_url)
```

I got the authorized url from my code. I need to get the callback url (http://localhost:3000/?code=AQDG8ZppeLo5u9UWWOPz0HAMZn303IDma6rTedLIRELFfHT1udSw4WWVpJIT1FXIsXRqg-on_fYUPm5vLFPEnMlmpAVMNKMreSxN0gZKKp_DM8EvrnMARGXJBYuJKdoke5Tpme4gbtSUGMd_OZ7LIsvi_208JSI6qFvhuFJ-m_xpfCgqf0eaxp0d1Q2s0AjmVDrQ2wqX24Ye7yv7-77Om1ZSzURUkCGTLAxwinVEVA). Is there any solution to get redirect url by authorized url using python requests

Comment: Your code should be as http(s) server. [This way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419872/spotify-api-getting-404-as-a-response-trying-to-find-current-song/75424917#75424917) is possible to get the redirect URL.