# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) (Jmeter)

Tags: json, testing, jmeter, postman

When making a request in postman - status 200, when making the same request in jmeter - status 500 and an error:

{"status":"fail","message":"Internal Server Error","system_message":"Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAEur.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvwdG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qql0b.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp0m8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pmYc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3tea.png)

Comment: Please tell me what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Given you send the same request you should be getting the same response.

For example I fail to see where did you get this [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header in your JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

My expectation is that if you remove this header the server will stop treating the request as a JSON payload and won't return [JSONDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0) anymore

If you have troubles copying and pasting 5 headers from Postman to JMeter you can always record the API call from your browser or upstream application using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) or JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Comment: Managed to solve the problem:

The user-agent was copied from the postman header and pasted into the jmeter request header