# Second for loop is ignored when I iterate through a file

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, dictionary

This is a simplified version of my code. Basically I have a file of general format:

```
2 3 5
4 8 9
etc
```

for n lines, and I must organize the file into a dictionary. Before this, I need a sum of one of the data points, so I iterate through the file to create a sum first, then iterate back through each line again in a second for suite to create a nested dictionary data structure. But for some reason the second suite is completely ignored.

This is a simplified version, so obviously some things could be moved around, but in the real file I really do need two separate loops because one of the values is a percentage based on the total sum in the file which is only fully defined after the end of the first for loop.

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
dict = {}
for line in file:
    v1, v2, v3 = file.split(' ')
    sum += v1
for line in file:
    v1, v2, v3 = file.split(' ')
    key = v1
    subkey = v2
    ratio = v3/sum
    value = ratio
    dict[key] = [subkey],[value]
print(dict)
```

For some reason this just gives

```
{}
```

Which is taking the original assignment of the dictionary and ignoring the second for iteration. If I try to print anything in the second suite, like just v1, it is ignored. If I put it in the first `for` loop, it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to "rewind" the file handler to the beginning of the file.

When you open the file, the pointer is at the very beginning. Once the first `for` loop is finished, the pointer is at the end of the file. In the second `for` loop the pointer is still at the end, so it just does nothing.

By adding

```
file.seek(0)
```

just before the second `for` loop, the pointer is moved back to the beginning of the file, allowing you to read the file again from the beginning.