# python list of floats from text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a list of floats from a text file with this code:

```
exam_data_file = open('exam_data.txt','r')
exam_data = exam_data_file.readlines()
exam_data1 = []

for line1 in exam_data_file:
    line1 = float(line1)
    exam_data1.append(line1)

 print(exam_data1)
```

but the output is simply: `[]`

Can someone please help?!

Now I get this error message regardless of the changes I make:

```
line1 = float(line1)


ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3.141592654
2.718281828
1.414213562
0.707106781
0.017453293
```

Comment: Share the content of your input file

Comment: 3.141592654
   2.718281828
   1.414213562
   0.707106781
   0.017453293

Comment: How is that content arranged in the input file?  All on one line, separated by spaces?  Each number on a separate line?  If the latter, are there any lines in the file that *don't* contain a number (e.g., a blank line at the start or end)?

Comment: Each number is on a separate line, but there are no blank lines

Comment: @Dan1, what did you change in your code to cause it to stop outputing `[]` and start raising the error?  i'm pretty, pretty, pretty sure that you don't get this error message "regardless of the changes [you] make." that's a _crazy_ thing to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two problems in your code:

- The first problem is that you are actually reading the file two times. One time line 2 (`exam_data_file.readlines()`) and one second time line 5 while executing the for-loop. You can't read a file twice. For further information [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906148/2286508).
- The second problem is that `line1` is currently a whole line in your file (in your case a chain of separate floats), and not a single float as you expected it to be. That's why you get the `Invalid literal` error. You have to split it into separate numbers in order to call `float` upon them. That's why you have to call the string's [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

Try this instead:

```
exam_data_file = open('exam_data.txt','r')
exam_data1 = []

for line in exam_data_file:
    exam_data1.extend([float(i) for i in line.split()])

print(exam_data1)
```

Output:

```
[3.141592654, 2.718281828, 1.414213562, 0.707106781, 0.017453293]
```

Comment: @Dan1: Could you copy paste the full traceback please?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Aliber/Desktop/CSC_108/Python lab b/data3.py", line 4, in <module>
    line1 = float(line1)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3.141592654
2.718281828
1.414213562
0.707106781
0.017453293

Comment: @Dan1: See my edited post :) I will now write explanations of the changes I made

Comment: @Controll, i'm not following your reasoning.  you say, "The second problem is that `line1` is currently a string . . ."  but that alone is not a problem.  strings can be cast as floats: e.g., `float('1.2')` returns `1.2`.  can you rephrase?

Comment: @dbliss You are absolutely right. see my edited post :)

Comment: @dbliss: But the traceback itself says all the information is in one single line. See the third comment on this post.

Comment: i think that's a consequence of it being in a comment -- comments don't show new lines.

Comment: @dbliss: I understand. But that's not the point. The message "invalid literal for float(): .... " Means the whole literal quoted in the exception was passed as and argument to `float`"

Comment: oh, totally agree.  but that raises a new question.  why does a single element in `readlines()` contain multiple lines?  (as opposed to, as you say, "a whole line.")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75063/discussion-between-controll-and-dbliss).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use **literal_eval** n -(easier to use)

You can read and print a simple list or multi-dimensional lists simply with **literal_eval**

```
from ast import literal_eval

f=open("demofile.txt",'r')

for line in f:
    new_list = literal_eval(line)

print(new_list)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59717679/10151945
This answer is quit relevant. 
here an example that i have done with :

```
from ast import literal_eval
file=open("student_list.txt",'r')
for student in file:
    student_list_final = literal_eval(student)
print(student_list_final)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`for line1 in exam_data_file:`

should be this :

```
for line1 in exam_data :
```

you are referring to a wrong object

Comment: It would still work though. Iterating through the file object is actually the recommended way to read lines in Python.

Comment: @pzp but *after* `readlines` the pointer is at the end of the file

Comment: @Akhil Thayyil's answer is still wrong though. ```readlines()``` does not strip whitespace (i.e. newlines), so there will still be an error when OP attempts to convert to floats.

Comment: @pzp: There's no problem with trailing or leading whitespace (including newlines) when converting a string to a float or an int.

Comment: @pzp Thanks for notifying

Comment: @Akhil Thayyil : Whoops, you were right to begin with; I didn't realize that float ignores trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You've made an error choosing the error to iterate over in the for loop.

```
for line1 in exam_data: # not the file!
    line1 = float(line1)
    exam_data1.append(line1)
```

This could be further improved with

```
exam_data = []
with open('exam_data.txt','r') as open_file:
    for line1 in open_file:
        line1 = float(line1)
        exam_data.append(line1)

print(exam_data)
```

The context handler (with syntax) will make sure you close the file after you have processed it!

Answer (score 0):

Since a file-like object is an iterable, you can just use `map`.

```
with open('exam_data.txt','r') as f:
    exam_data = map(float, f)
```