# Why BeautifulSoup is not showing the title in HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm making an easy **scraper** to see if I can get the value in an input that I need from a HTML I made. It always shows **None** as an answer, so I'm checkin with something more simple, the < title > in the html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # parsing
r = open("C:/Python27/Pruebas/pruebahtml.html")
print(r.read())

soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")
title = soup.title
print(title)
r.close()
```

But I'm still getting **None** as an answer, I have also used findALL, find_all and find to do this but I get some errors. Do anyone knows where's my mistake?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file.

Comment: Thanks, I was forgetting that
Now my question is.. if the user gives an input in the html and clicks a button, can I read the input he/she made using this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an empty string to bs4 because `print(r.read())` has moved the pointer to the end of the file, remove the `print(r.read())` and pass it to `BeautifulSoup(`  or call `r.seek(0)` and pass. Once you call read, readlines on or iterate over a file object the iterator is consumed so there is nothing left to read.

Comment: Thanks, I was forgetting that. Now my question is.. if the user gives an input in the html and clicks a button, can I read the input he/she made using this??

Comment: @JoshuaCazares, you would be better asking a new question for that spcifically.

Comment: It alls depends on how you are getting the html in the first place, make sure if you ask another question to add a clear example of what you want.

Comment: Welll, im getting the html by doing open(file.html), I would love to give the code, but I have to wait to make a new question

Comment: Add it to pastebin and  I will have a look