# readlines() method of File Object in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a quick question about the readlines() method for file objects in Python.

I have a file (file1.txt) containing the following:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

I know I can use readlines() on this file in the interpreter like so:

```
>>>f = open('file1.txt', 'r+')
>>>f.readlines()
['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n', 'four\n', 'five\n']
```

Similarly, I can do this:

```
>>>f = open('file1.txt', 'r+')
>>>lines = f.readlines()
>>>lines
['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n', 'four\n', 'five\n']
```

However, it seems like I can only run the readlines() method once:

```
>>>f = open('file1.txt', 'r+')
>>>f.readlines()
['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n', 'four\n', 'five\n']
>>>lines = f.readlines()
>>>lines
[]
```

What is going on here?  Why does f.readlines() return an empty list the second time I call it?

Thanks.

Comment: You also can only run`f.read()` once unless you run `f.seek(0)`. This maybe is a dupe. Let me search about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the first question asking this.  My google skills are apparently lacking.

Answer (score 1):

When you read the file once, the file pointer have moved to the end of the file, you have to call `f.seek(0)` to move the file pointer back to the start.