# Python reading nothing from file

Tags: python, file

I've written a simple program to check if something has been written to a file, and if it hasn't then written to the file. 
Once that is done, I then want to read from the file, but it keeps reading a blank line?

```
with open("leaderboard.txt", "r+") as infile:
if infile.readline() == "Rank\tName\tTime (secs)":
    print("Already written to.\n")
else:
    print("Writing headers\n")
    infile.write("Rank\tName\tTime (secs)")

contents = infile.read()
print(contents)
```

The current result I am getting is:

```
Already written to.
```

(followed by two blank lines)

Would anyone know the solution to my problem? Thanks!

SOLUTION: Once the file is read once, the file pointer is then positioned at the end of the file. After moving the file pointer back to the beginning I can reread the file.
To reposition file pointer use `infile.seek(0)`. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

Comment: Is there anything in the file?

Comment: Briefly: when you do `infile.read()`, there's nothing left to read because you're at the end of the file.

Comment: Besides, if the goal is to create a header, your code will either add it to an empty file (with no linefeed at the end, note) or add it to the middle of a non-empty file. You should reconsider what sort of input you expect to use, and what result you want to end up with.

Comment: Yeah, there's "Rank    Name    Time (secs)" in the file

Comment: Why am I at the end of the file after doing infile.read()?

Comment: You are at the end of the file _before_ doing that. You read a line, then possible write something, and then there's nothing else in the file. When you try to read the file at that point, it's at the end, so there's nothing left.

Comment: How would I resolve my issue? So how would I read from the file, from the first line, but still do the first line check thing at the start?