# Parsing a line from an ASCII HDR file python

Tags: python, parsing, matplotlib, ascii

I am having difficulty parsing a line from an hdr file I have. When I print read (data) like in the code below the command window outputs the contents of the hdr file. However, when I try to parse out a line or a column , like the script below, it outputs nothing in the command window.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = open('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr', 'r')
data = f.read()
print (data)

for line in f:
    columns = line.split()
    time = float(columns[2])
    print (time)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this two lines and execute your code again:

```
data = f.read()
print (data)
```

Then change your loop:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    columns = line.split()
    time = float(columns[2])
    print (time)
```

Calling read() reads through the entire file and leaves the read cursor at the end of the file (with nothing more to read). If you are looking to read a certain number of lines at a time you could use readline(), readlines()

Read the post [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

Comment: Removing the line `print (data)` will have no effect; the cursor is already at the end of the file at that point.

Comment: He said " When I print read (data) like in the code below the command window outputs the contents of the hdr file" and after that cursor pointed to end of file, I mean to remove this line and try again

Comment: Your answer begins "Remove this line: `print (data)`".  Doing that will change absolutely nothing.

Comment: @DSM Sorry, That's my fault, I changed it.