# Not entering 'for' loop? Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

For whatever reason, my code is not entering the 'for' loop below in line 85.

The file input_fileA is open. Does anyone have a clue why? This is python 2.7.

```
 84 if (counter_shiftA == counter_shiftB):
 85     for line in input_fileA:
 86         print line
 87         if shiftBEntryA.strip() in line:
 88             print "Hit a matched line"
 89             counter1 += 1
 90             flag = True
 91             output_file.write(line)
 92         elif shiftEEntryA.strip() in line:
 93             output_file.write(line)
 94             break
 95         elif flag:
 96             output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: what is the declaration of input_fileA?

Comment: Does `counter_shiftA == counter_shiftB` evaluate to `True`?

Comment: Is `input_fileA` already exhausted? Or empty?

Comment: Is it going in to your condition? What does `input_fileA` look like?

Comment: Yes, the counter_shiftA == counter_shiftB statement is true and works.

Comment: input_fileA is not empty, but how can I check if it is exhausted?

Comment: @CookiesMonster what is `input_fileA` exactly? Is it *the* file object? Did you do work on that file already before entering that condition? Did you try seeing if the file has data in it before starting the loop?

Comment: Yes, it's the file object. Yes, I worked on that file before that condition. It has data in it.

Comment: Have you used `for line in input_file1:`  anywhere before `line 87`?

Comment: Yes, I have used that same line before the current for statement.

Comment: That's the issue. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code to see how you are using `input_fileA`, it could be that the file objected has exhausted. If you are looking to reuse the same object and bring it back to the beginning of the file for future operations then you need to do a `input_file1.seek(0)` to point it back to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `input_file1.seek(0)` before `for line in input_file1.readlines():` of `line 87`. Since, you mentioned you have called the line before.
For more details, you can check [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.