# Failing to make a line-by-line list from a file?

Tags: python, list, file, iteration

This is what I have (which includes extra processing):

```
import string

def main():
    fileInput = open("A tisket a tasket.txt",'r')
    characters, words, lines = countEmUp(fileInput)
    printCounts(characters, words, lines)
    tokenList = splitToTokens(fileInput)
    print(tokenList)

def countEmUp(someFileInput):
    lines, words, chars = 0, 0, 0
    for line in someFileInput:
        chars += len(line)  # using += for nice and concise updates
        words += len(line.split())
        lines += 1
    return chars, words, lines

def printCounts(ch,wd,ln):
    print("Your file contains the following:")
    print("Characters:",ch)
    print("Words:",wd)
    print("Lines:",ln)

def splitToTokens(aFileInput):
    tokenList = []
    for line in aFileInput:
        tokenList.extend(line.split())
    return tokenList

  main()
```

The problem starts at the splitToTokens function.

What I'm *trying* to do is create an empty list, iterate through a file I opened for reading line-by-line, and add the tokens in that line to my tokenList so I can process the tokens later.

When I print tokenList in my main() function it's still an empty list.

I suspect that maybe it has to do with my fileInput already being called? I'm trying not to open the file more than once.

Comment: what's your `aFileInput` you pass in?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: show more of the code (i.e. where you create aFileInput)

Comment: I think the code you show is OK. I suspect the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnAnderson even if I print(tokenList) right in the function it's still an empty list [].

Comment: you have to call your function `main()` to run, you just defined it.

Comment: @Tiny.D Well, I'm doing this in IDLE so you can either run it and type main() or add it to the end of the code. Which I actually did but did not paste. I'm not saying that I get no output. I'm saying that when I print it, I get [] instead of a full list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to re-read file, you have to move the cursor to the beginning of the file:

```
file.seek(0)
```

change your code to:

```
import string

def main():
    fileInput = open("A tisket a tasket.txt",'r')    
    characters, words, lines = countEmUp(fileInput)
    fileInput.seek(0) #offset of 0
    printCounts(characters, words, lines)
    tokenList = splitToTokens(fileInput)
    print(tokenList)

def countEmUp(someFileInput):
    lines, words, chars = 0, 0, 0
    for line in someFileInput:
        chars += len(line)  # using += for nice and concise updates
        words += len(line.split())
        lines += 1
    return chars, words, lines

def printCounts(ch,wd,ln):
    print("Your file contains the following:")
    print("Characters:",ch)
    print("Words:",wd)
    print("Lines:",ln)

def splitToTokens(aFileInput):
    tokenList = []
    for line in aFileInput:
        tokenList.extend(line.split())
    return tokenList
main()
```

Comment: This is spot on. This other post may help to understand it better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file