# How to enter into enumarate() loop more than one time

Tags: python, loops, csv, enumerate, read-data

I want to read a big data file 100 by 100. But my script reads only first 100 line, then it never enters in "for loop" for the rest. 
More clearly, in the end, I get only lines from 0 to 100, but I want also 100-200, 200-300, 300-400 etc. I can't see what the problem is.

(I use python 3.4. All data in .csv file is number. I already know to use `islice()` but I want particularly use `enumerate()` function.)

I would be very happy if you could help.

```
pathInput = "input.csv"
f = open(pathInput, 'r')
sizeOfList = 100
iD = 0
while iD<1000:
    dataset = []
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
       if i<(iD + sizeOfList):
           dataset.append(line)
    print(dataset)
    iD += sizeOfWindow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, files objects are not a list, but it has a cursor that gets moved towards the end of the file as `read` is called (which `enumerate` basically does).  The cursor basically is placed at the end of the file and thus nothing can be read anymore on the second loop.

Two ways this can be solved:

1) Read the whole file into memory first, and cast the `enumerate` call into a list, e.g.:

```
pathInput = "input.csv"
f = open(pathInput, 'r')
idx_line = enumerate(f)
id = 0
while id < 1000:
    dataset = []
    for idx, line in items:
        ...
```

2) Call `seek` on the file object to get back to the beginning of the file before calling `enumerate(f)`.

```
while id < 1000:
    f.seek(0)
    dataset = []
```

Also refer to:

- [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

However, given that you probably have a CSV file, you probably want to try the following:

- [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: for the first solution, i didn't want to read all data. The second one works for me. Thanks you so much :)

Comment: a small question, does readlines() works with the same logic? we need to use seek() again?

Comment: Yes, any read operation will move the cursor forward towards the end of the stream/file.