# How to get a list from a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to get the contents of a file in a list. For reference: these are the contents of the file:

```
1. item1
2. item2
3. item3
```

I am able to open the files, and when I do `file.read()`, all I get from the interpreter is an empty string:

```
>>> file = open("C:\\Users\\vivrd\\Desktop\\testing.txt")
>>> file.read()
''
```

If I do `file.readlines()`, it displays a list, but even though the python docs say that `file.readlines()` returns a list, whenever I try to assign a variable to it (to access the list), all I get is an empty list:

```
>>> file.readlines() 
['1. item1\n', '2. item2\n', '3. item3'] #returns the list   
>>> item = file.readlines()
>>> item #but the list is empty!
[]
```

I have also tried to loop through the file, but it doesn't print out anything:

```
>>> for line in file:
print(line)


>>>
```

Also, for some reason, `file.readlines()` is only working once. I tried it a second time, and the interpreter didn't even display anything:

```
>>> file.readlines()
[]
```

My target is to get a list that looks like this: `["1. item1", "2. item2", "3. item3"]` or even with the escape sequences (though not preferable): `["1. item1 \n", "2. item2 \n", "3. item3"]`

How can I get to this point? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work only once, because after that, python is done reading the file ([here's a question that discusses this in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)). Read it once and store it in a variable:

```
>>> f = open("C:\\Users\\vivrd\\Desktop\\testing.txt")
>>> items = f.readlines() # items should now be a list of lines in the file
>>> f.close() # make sure to close the file
```

If you want to re-read, move the 'cursor' back to the beginning of the file (before closing) using `seek`:

```
>>> items = f.readlines()
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> more_items = f.readlines()
>>> f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with these lines of codes .

```
with open(filename , "r") as file:
     content=file.readlines()
for lines in content:
    print(lines)
```