# Python - txt file not detected between multiple for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have been getting an error where a '.txt' file that I have opened will not be detected by multiple loops.

```
hand = open('filter_test.txt')   # Open 1

# Loop 1
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search(r'^X.*:', line):
        print(line)


# I can still see 'hand' here.
print(hand)

# If 'Open 2' is not there, the 'Loop 2' will not pick up 'filter_test.txt'

hand = open('filter_test.txt')    # Open 2

#Loop 2   
for line in hand:
    # If 'Open 2' is not present, line will not print anything here.
    print(line)
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search(r'^X-\S+:', line):
        print(line)
```

I can still see 'hand' between 'Loop 1' and 'Loop 2', but if I do not have the 'Open 2', 'Loop 2' will not pick it up.

Any idea why this is? It seems silly having to reopen a file for each loop I want to run

Cheers

Comment: close the file using `hand.close()` before you try to open it again

Comment: After the first for loop, you already read all the content of the file. There is nothing else to read, the second for loop is moot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

Comment: @John The issue is not the supposedly missing `close()`. It is that the iterator reached the `StopIteration`, there is nothing else to iterate over.

Comment: I mean, thats why `close()` could be handy, to reset the reading of a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
hand = open('filter_test.txt')  
hand_content = hand.read()
hand.close()

for line in hand_content:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search(r'^X.*:', line):
        print(line)

print(hand_content)

for line in hand_content:
    print(line)
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search(r'^X-\S+:', line):
        print(line)
```

the problem was that you try to open a file that you didn't close the overcome for that is to store the file content in a variable and use the variable for the loops.

Comment: Explain why this would work and why OP's version does not work?

Comment: Tnx for that note added an explanation

Comment: @LeoArad - Thank you, makes sense now

Comment: @Keldorn Thank you for the prompt for more explanation, I needed it :)