# Iterating particular lines of txt files multiple time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to add particular segment of txt files multiple times to another txt file

Input.txt

```
 Heading 
 Heading2 
    
 Heading3 
    
 Line1
 Line2
    
 Line3
 Line4
```

Outputfile.txt(expected Output)

```
 Heading 
 Heading2 
    
 Heading3 
    
 Line1
 Line2
 
 Line1
 Line2

 Line1
 Line2
    
 Line3
 Line4
```

I want to repeat Line1 and Line2 multiple times.

```
LinesToRepete=[6,7,8]
with open("Input.txt") as f:
    with open("output.txt", "a+") as f1:
        for k in range(2):
            for i, line in enumerate(f):
                if i in LinesToRepete:
                        f1.write(line)
                else:
                    f1.write(line)
```

Comment: The tags suggest you need a solution that works in Python 2 as well as Python 3? Perhaps make that explicit in the question. Also, what is `TestcaseLine` - you never defined it?

Comment: Any one of it will also do ..Removing the tag

Comment: It appears that you don't just want to repeat lines 6 and 7, but also line 8 (empty)? What other values should work for `lines_to_repeat`? Is it always just the first and last line of the section to repeat? Or should it be able to repeat multiple sections?

Comment: sorry I copy pasted my code form main code. so typo.Yes i need to repete 6,7,8 lines. Only these lines must repete , Not other part of text file

Comment: Please describe how you identify the lines to be repeated.  By position (because of the `enumerate`) or by content? BTW: `with` supports creating multiple contexts. And I suggest to invert the loops

Comment: Anything is fine. I can identify 6,7 line by content, But not line 8 as there are many blank lines. So looking for best-suited one.  where i can provide inputs to number of  times to repete

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple issues;

- When you read a line from a file handle, you consume it; it cannot be read again (unless you close and reopen the file handle, or rewind it). See e.g. [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)
- Your code would repeat the lines next to each other. If you managed to sort out the previous bug, you would get repeated `Line 1` followed by repeated `Line 2` etc. By your example, you want to repeat the entire block `k` times, in the same sequence.
- `enumerate` starts its numbering at 0; you can switch to 1-based indexing (or generally any base number) by passing an additional parameter.

Here's an attempt to rectify these bugs.  For simplicity, this is just reading standard input and writing to standard output. (This is actually a useful convention because this way, you can use it on any file, without needing to hard-code anything or parse the command line.)

```py
import sys

lines_to_repeat = [5, 6, 7]

memory = []
for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, 1):
    if i in lines_to_repeat:
        memory.append(line)
    elif memory:
        sys.stdout.write(''.join(memory))
        memory = []
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

If you want to repeat more than once, you can add a loop in the `elif memory:` block, or just multiply the `join`ed string with the number of additional repeats (in Python, `3 * "abc"` evaluates to `"abcabcabc"`).

Demo: https://ideone.com/LGOBHX

An organizing assumption is that you want a single block of contiguous lines to be repeated; if you want to repeat multiple disparate blocks, that will take some rather heavy refactoring. (Probably ask a new question with your real requirements then.)