# Lines in text file won't iterate through for loop Python

Tags: python, loops, bert-language-model

I am trying to iterate through my questions and lines in my .txt file. Now this question may have been asked before, but I am really having trouble with this.

this is what I have right now:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

max_seq_length = 512

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("henryk/bert-base-multilingual-cased-finetuned-dutch-squad2")
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("henryk/bert-base-multilingual-cased-finetuned-dutch-squad2")

f = open("glad.txt", "r")

questions = [
    "Welke soorten gladiatoren waren er?",
    "Wat is een provocator?",
    "Wat voor helm droeg een retiarius?",
]
for question in questions:
    print(f"Question: {question}")
    for _ in range(len(question)):
        for line in f:
            text = str(line.split("."))
            inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(question,
                                           text,
                                           add_special_tokens=True,
                                           max_length=100,
                                           truncation=True,
                                           return_tensors="pt")
            input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].tolist()[0]

            text_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids)
            answer_start_scores, answer_end_scores = model(**inputs, return_dict=False)

            answer_start = torch.argmax(
                answer_start_scores
            )  # Get the most likely beginning of answer with the argmax of the score
            answer_end = torch.argmax(
                answer_end_scores) + 1  # Get the most likely end of answer with the argmax of the score

            answer = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(
                tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids[answer_start:answer_end]))

            print(text)
            # if answer == '[CLS]':
            #   continue
            # elif answer == '':
            #   continue
            # else:
            #   print(f"Answer: {answer}")
            #   print(f"Answer start: {answer_start}")
            #   print(f"Answer end: {answer_end}")
            #   break
```

and this is the output:

```
> Question: Welke soorten gladiatoren waren er?
> ['Er waren vele soorten gladiatoren, maar het meest kwamen de thraex, de retiarius en de murmillo voor', ' De oudste soorten gladiatoren droegen de naam van een volk: de Samniet en de Galliër', '\n']
> ['Hun uitrusting bestond uit dezelfde wapens als die waarmee de Samnieten en Galliërs in hun oorlogen met de Romeinen gewoonlijk vochten', '\n']
> ['De Thraciër (thraex) verscheen vanaf de tweede eeuw voor Chr', ' Hij had een vrij klein  kromzwaard (sica), een klein rond (soms vierkant) schild, een helm en lage beenplaten', " De retiarius ('netvechter') had een groot net (rete) met een doorsnee van 3 m, een drietand en soms  ook een dolk", '\n']
> ['Hij had alleen bescherming om zijn linkerarm en -schouder', ' Vaak droeg hij ook een bronzen beschermingsplaat (galerus) van zijn nek tot linkerelleboog', ' Vaak vocht de retiarius tegen de secutor die om die reden ook wel contraretiarius werd genoemd', '\n']
> ['Hij had een langwerpig schild en een steekzwaard', ' Opvallend was zijn eivormige helm zonder rand en met een metalen kam, waarschijnlijk zo ontworpen om minder makkelijk in het net van de retiarius vast te haken', ' Een provocator (‘uitdager’) vocht doorgaans tegen een andere provocator', '\n']
> ['Hij viel zijn tegenstander uit een onverwachte hoek plotseling aan', ' Hij had een lang rechthoekig schild, een borstpantser, een beenplaat alleen over het linkerbeen, een helm en een kort zwaard', '']
> Question: Wat is een provocator?
> Question: Wat voor helm droeg een retiarius?
```

But the sentences are supposed to repeat in the other questions too.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? It is probably something really easy, but I really don't seem the find the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add `f.seek(0)` after your first parse through the file. This is because when you read the file once, the cursor is at the end of the file, after which `for line in f` does not read the file from the beginning again. Please refer to [Tim and Nunser's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file) which explains it well.

Something like this:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

max_seq_length = 512

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("henryk/bert-base-multilingual-cased-finetuned-dutch-squad2")
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("henryk/bert-base-multilingual-cased-finetuned-dutch-squad2")

f = open("glad.txt", "r")

questions = [
    "Welke soorten gladiatoren waren er?",
    "Wat is een provocator?",
    "Wat voor helm droeg een retiarius?",
]
for question in questions:
    print(f"Question: {question}")
    for _ in range(len(question)):
        for line in f:
            text = str(line.split("."))
            inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(question,
                                           text,
                                           add_special_tokens=True,
                                           max_length=100,
                                           truncation=True,
                                           return_tensors="pt")
            input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].tolist()[0]

            text_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids)
            answer_start_scores, answer_end_scores = model(**inputs, return_dict=False)

            answer_start = torch.argmax(
                answer_start_scores
            )  # Get the most likely beginning of answer with the argmax of the score
            answer_end = torch.argmax(
                answer_end_scores) + 1  # Get the most likely end of answer with the argmax of the score

            answer = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(
                tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids[answer_start:answer_end]))

            print(text)
        f.seek(0) # reset cursor to beginning of the file
```

Comment: Thank you! Both the answers work exactly the same as the answer above

Answer (score 1):

Your `f` is just an open file which is exhausted the first time through. I think you meant this:

```py
f = list(open("glad.txt", "r"))
```

Comment: Now the lines endlessly keep iterating at one question

Comment: Perhaps you don't need the second for loop: `for _ in range(len(question)):`?