# How do I combine two print functions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the output of two regexs run against the same file.

I have tried

```
import re
with open("C:\\Users\\frank\Documents\\file-with-digits.txt") as myfile:
    print(re.findall(r'organizationID as int\s*=\s*(\d+)', myfile.read()))
    print(re.findall(r'organizationID\s*=\s*(\d+)', myfile.read()))
```

and

```
import re
with open("C:\\Users\\frank\Documents\\file-with-digits.txt") as myfile:
    print(((re.findall(r'organizationID as int\s*=\s*(\d+)', myfile.read())), re.findall(r'organizationID\s*=\s*(\d+)', myfile.read())))
```

In each case the second print statement shows no output.

If I run them separately they both show their unique output. How do I combine them so I see the output of both regular expressions? I can open the file twice of course and run them separately but I am thinking it must be possible to combine them.

Comment: Calling `file.read()` exhausts the file contents, so there is nothing left for the second pattern to match.  If you want to re-use the file contents, assign them to a variable and then you can refer to the variable as many times as you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your question: [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file/3906563)

In your specific case, what you want to do is:

```
import re
with open("C:\\Users\\frank\Documents\\file-with-digits.txt") as myfile:
    file_contents = myfile.read()
    print(re.findall(r'organizationID as int\s*=\s*(\d+)', file_contents ))
    print(re.findall(r'organizationID\s*=\s*(\d+)', file_contents ))
```

Also, as a rule of thumb: I/O-operations like reading a file are generally slow. So even if calling `read()` on a file twice had the effect you expected, it would be a good idea to do it just once and store the result in a variable, so you can re-use it.