# python : Read HTTPResponse twice

Tags: python, stream, httpresponse, urllib3

I have `urllib3.response.HTTPResponse` (a "file-like" object) and `lxml.html.lxml_parse` that takes only a file path, an URL or a "file-like" object (in case of `HTTPResponse` it also extracts the URL). Also I need the content from the response.

The answers from [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file) do not fit the situation since the stream consumes while reading into a variable and `.seek` is not defined for `HTTPResponse`.

`copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy` do not work too.

Comment: Read the content into a variable first and then pass that string to lxml.html.fromstring instead?

Comment: @IainShelvington Not a bad idea. But it requires many changes in the third-party package. Nevertheless, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: What's the third party package? If you have access to the lxml html object you could convert that to a string instead?

Comment: I can trace the input path to the one of its usage but it does not mean that the properties of the input can be used in separate things. However, I was able to solve my problem using `Element` from `lxml`