# Hashing file in Python produces same hash for any file

Tags: python, caching

I'm implementing caching for my program's raw outputs and to make it work with same name files I decided to name the json file as the file's md5 cache. But any file I pass returns the same hash - `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`
(same issue with other hashing algorithms)

Here's the code I have:

```
    def __init__(self, filepath: str):
        self.file = filepath
        self.file_format = self.get_file_format()
        with open(self.file, 'rb') as f:
            self.nbt = nbt.File.load(f, gzipped=True).unpack()

            md5 = hashlib.md5()

            chunk = 0
            while chunk != b'':
                chunk = f.read(1024)
                md5.update(chunk)

            print(md5.hexdigest())

            self.cache = f'../main/schematic_cache/{md5.hexdigest()}.json'
            if not exists(self.cache):
                with open(self.cache, 'w') as j:
                    json.dump({'file': self.file}, j, indent=2)
```

How can I fix this or is there a better way to store this kind of cache?

Comment: ``d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`` is the md5 of an empty byte string. You are not actually updating the hash, which indicates no data is read from the file.

Comment: Does ``nbt.File.load`` consume the file content? Files are streams, reading them once "exhausts" them unless reset to their beginning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the question comments by MisterMiyagi:

> `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` is the md5 of an empty byte string.
> You are not actually updating the hash, which indicates no data is read from the file.
>
> Files are streams, reading them once "exhausts" them unless reset to their beginning. [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)