# Finding the length of a txt file without moving the cursor

Tags: python

```
file = open("accounts.txt", "r")
num = len(file.readlines())
file = open("accounts.txt", "r")
```

this is my current solution but it just feels wrong, is there a better way of finding num without reopening the file to reset the cursor?

Comment: You don't have to reopen the file to reset the cursor, you can use `file.seek(0)`

Comment: There's no way to count lines without reading the file. If you wanted the length in bytes there are ways, but not lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

Answer (score 0):

From [Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73643719/finding-the-length-of-a-txt-file-without-moving-the-cursor/73643914#comment130046839_73643719), this

```
file.seek(0)
```

is close enough to what I was looking for.