# creating user login using .txtfile and dictionary

Tags: python

I need to create a user login program that reads a file that has all user details on and then saves that to a dictionary or list.

this dictionary/list will be the variable that my if statement will run through to check the login credentials are correct.

Please excuse all variable names, they are just place holding whilst the code is sorted.

I have been trying to find solutions that do not include json or anything else, as i am learning to code and not able to use this to complete this program.

```
with open("user.txt","r") as user_log:
    try:
        users = user_log
        user_key = {}
        for line in user_log:
            key,value = line.strip().split(',')
            user_key[key] = value
    except Exception:
        print("File can not be found")
    


username = input("Please enter username: ")
if username in user_key:
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if password == user_key[username]:
            print(f"Welcome", {username})
    else: 
        print("incorrect username or password. Please try again.")
else: 
    print("that is not a valid username.")
    quit
```

The code above says my username and password is incorrect even though it is not & it will also continue with the program instead of ending  and i'm unsure why. i have been staring at it for too long and don't really know what is right or wrong at this point.

Please let me know where my mistakes are and how to improve this block of code.

Comment: Once you have done `users = user_log.read()`, the file pointer is at the end of the file, so `for line in user_log:` has nothing to read. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file (but not an exact duplicate).

Comment: You are missing parenthesis after quit, or maybe it just fell in the copy?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code:

```
with open("user.txt", "r") as user_log:
    try:
        users = user_log
        user_key = {}
        for line in user_log:
            key, value = line.strip().split(',')
            user_key[key] = value
    except Exception:
        print("File can not be found")

username = input("Please enter username: ")
if username in user_key:
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if password == user_key[username]:
        print(f"Welcome", {username})
    else:
        print("incorrect username or password. Please try again.")
else:
    print("that is not a valid username.")
```

And it works as intended.

The issue I think is that this code expects to have a txt file having csv data like here:

```
myuser,mypass
anotheruser,anotherpass
```

Comment: Thanks @Pitto this was helpful as the data I saved in the txt file like:                                          'admin,  adm1n' I added a space to .strip(',') and is now working as intended

Comment: I am glad it helped! If this solved your problem please mark the answer as correct and, if you want, also upvote it.